# Colon in JSON string

Tags: jquery, json, string, escaping

Can I escape a colon : that is inside a JSON string? Currently this object/value set

```
{ pn: "MT46H128M16LFCK-5 IT:A", 
  visible: false, 
  url: "/$ws$/29/1/products/ProductDetails.html?product=products/dram/MT46H128M16LFCK-5 IT" 
}
```

doesn't get read. I suspect it's due to the `:A` in the `pn` value. How do I escape it or otherwise grab it?

Comment: You do not need to escape colons. It's really only quotes that ever need to be escaped in JSON.

Comment: Yep, I read your post wrong with my initial answer (thought it was a jquery selector for some reason)... sorry.

The space in the URL is a little dubious to me though.

Comment: @gabe, Also / in some cases.

Comment: @Arashsoft: No, `/` has no special meaning within a JSON string. It's just `/`. PHP erroneously escapes them, but that's just a PHP issue.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder, we have to do so if we want to embed our JSON in a `<script>` tag. That is why php does that by default. http://stackoverflow.com/a/1580682/3328979

Comment: @Arashsoft: No, you don't. **If** you're outputting JSON within the body of a `<script>` tag, you have to escape the `/` in `</script>`. Not others.

Comment: In addition to quotes, backslashes also need to be escaped (from experience, not the stndard)

Answer (score 11):

If that's your actual JSON, your problem is that the identifiers (pn, visible, url), need to be quoted ("pn", "visible", "url").

As the comment said, colons don't need to be escaped in JSON string literals.

Comment: Hmm, except the other value pairs work perfectly well. 

E.g. 

{ pn: "MT45W8MW16BGX-856 AT", visible: true, url: "/$ws$/29/1/products/ProductDetails.html?product=products/dram/MT45W8MW16BGX-856 AT" } 

Works well and returns results.

Comment: I'm using it in conjunction with autoSuggest/jQuery. Unfortunately all our dev sites are behind a firewall, so I cannot list actual urls, but here is the jquery call:

Comment: jQuery("input#search").autoSuggest(webPartItems, {
                selectedItemProp: "pn", 
                searchObjProps: "pn", 
                selectedValuesProp: "url", 
                startText:"Search by part number or keyword", 
                retrieveLimit:10, 
                minChars:2, 
                emptyText:"No Results. Type MT1...", 
                selectionLimit:1, 
                selectionAdded: function(elem){ 
                    var pLink = jQuery('input.as-values').attr("value");
                    window.location=pLink.split(',')[0];
                }