# Why is the slash an escapable character in JSON?

Tags: json, escaping, specifications, slash

[json.org](http://json.org) states, that forward slashes (aka solidus, `/`) can be escaped:

```
"\/"
```

However, unescaped slashes are valid, too:

```
"/"
```

What's the rational behind this? Does it come from the Javascript roots? (I.e., `"</script>"` is a problem in browser-based Javascript, see [Douglas Crockford's comment](https://crockford.com/javascript/script.html)) Or has it any other reason?

Comment: It does indeed have its roots in the `</script>` tag. You can see Douglas Crockford, the originator of the JSON specifications, present the rationale for it [here](https://youtu.be/-C-JoyNuQJs?t=386).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It seems, my first thought was correct.

`'\/' === '/'` in JavaScript, and JSON [almost](http://timelessrepo.com/json-isnt-a-javascript-subset) *is* valid JavaScript.
However, why are the other ignored escapes (like `\z`) not allowed in JSON?

The key for this was reading http://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/www/revsol.html, followed by http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/appendix/notes.html#h-B.3.2. The feature of the slash escape allows JSON to be embedded in HTML (as SGML) and XML.

Comment: Things like \b is used for backspace in JSON, allowing \z for z would make things confusing.

Answer (score 5):

I've just published [a review of this issue](http://mondotondo.com/2010/12/29/the-solidus-issue/) on my blog. I think you are right, that's the only reason. Also note that the slash is the only standard character allowed to be escaped.

Usually JSON encoders do it wrong and escape any slash they find along the way, while only the slash in `</script>` should be escaped, and maybe all the ones matched by the JavaScript RegExp `/<\/\w+/`, for the same reason.

Comment: Hm, interesting. But you, too, don't happen to know the source for the assumption?

Comment: "Also note that the slash is the only standard character allowed to be escaped." < Wrong. All characters can be escaped, some just through other methods.

Comment: I think I prefer JSON encoders who do it "wrong", because that makes things more consistent.