# "Text1/Text2" String is replaced by "Text1\/Text2" in android

Tags: android, json

When i try to run this code in android i am getting the resultant String as `"Name":"Text1\/Text2"` But the result should be `{"Name":"Text1/Text2"}`.

```
try {
    String str;
    JSONObject json = new JSONObject();

    json.put("Name", "Text1/Text2");

    str = json.toString();
} catch (JSONException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: what do you want and what its now..explain clearly..

Comment: please see the question again.

Comment: Its because the by default the android will convert your string into utf-8 encoding format so your `/` will be replaced with `\/`.

Comment: escape the `/` by a `\ `of your own, add it in your code in line 4

Comment: did you saw http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1580647/json-why-are-forward-slashes-escaped

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As @GrlHu said that by default the android will convert your string into utf-8 encoding format so your `/` will be replaced with `\/`. 
Please read the following two post 
1.  [JSON: why are forward slashes escaped?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1580647/json-why-are-forward-slashes-escaped) 
2. [Why is the slash an escapable character in JSON?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4264877/why-is-the-slash-an-escapable-character-in-json)
So instead of this you can use `getString(Name)` method. Hope you will get the perfect value.

```
try {
    String str;
    JSONObject json = new JSONObject();

    json.put("Name", "Text1/Text2");
    str = json.getString("Name");
    Log.e("test", str);
} catch (JSONException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: I fail to see why this has anything to do with UTF-8 encoding.

Comment: Please check the above link.

Comment: UTF-8 is not even mentioned in above links