# JSON Object in Java

Tags: java, json

how do I convert a string `url = "http://abcdef.com/"` to JSONObject having a field `"url" ="http://abcdef.com/"` ? The result I am getting is : `"url" = "http:\/\/abcdef.com"`.So, I am not able to get around '/'

Comment: Are you saying you have a problem with the escaped slashes? It's completely fine to have them escaped in a JSON string. Do you have a concrete problem with them?

Comment: I have to use to a JSON object having the url in the form "http://abcdef.com" without the escaped backslashes in my next module so, that is it

Comment: For the record (as per my deleted answer because the question was initially unclear), OP is using [json-simple](http://code.google.com/p/json-simple/) and want to prevent JS-escaping.

Comment: You are aware that the backslashes are only needed in the JSON repesentation? The actual string doesn't contain any backslashes.

Comment: "backslashes are only needed in the JSON" -- no, they are not *needed*, they are being escaped defensively. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1580647/json-why-are-forward-slashes-escaped

Answer (score 0):

If that's the way your JSONObject serializes strings (which *is* legal [as per the JSON spec](http://www.json.org/)), there's no way to get around it directly unless you alter the behavior of the JSONObject. (by rewriting, subclassing, or wrapping -- see below.)

Indirectly, if you have an opportunity to intercept the JSONObject output, convert to string, and replace all instances of `\/` with `/`.

**update:** I'm not familiar with the specific implementation you're using, but if you have existing code that expects a JSONObject and takes an *interface* rather than a particular class implementation, you could write a decorator or wrapper class that holds an instance to the "real" JSONObject class, and delegates everything to the JSONObject, but fixes up the conversion of strings so it converts `\/` to `/` after-the-fact automatically.

Comment: sry man, new here.. :) Exactly what I was trying to do in the meantime :). So what I do is I create a JSONObject with url field as "http:\/\/abcdef.com" Now to test if can be used without escaped backslshes, I parse it using JSONParser and then extract the url field of the JSONObject I created. It then returns it to me in the correct format(which it should have and hence can be used in the next module).. thanx all :)