# Making JSON not Escape Forward Slashes

Tags: java, json, org.json

This is an extenuation of this question:

[JSON: why are forward slashes escaped?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1580647/json-why-are-forward-slashes-escaped)

So I understand why JSON escapes the forwards slashes when I create a JSONArray that has Strings that contain URLs (links) in each of its indices. I would like to now know how to make JSON not escape these forward slashes when I serialize a String like so:

```
[['documentary', 'http://www.google.com/#q=documentary']]
```

into a JSONArray. I was thinking of iterating through the Strings and removing any instance where there is a backslash, but I was wondering if there was a more efficient way of doing this or a way to have it so that the above string would not automatically be escaped as follows:

```
[['documentary', 'http:\/\/www.google.com\/#q=documentary']]
```

Thank you! Let me know if anything is unclear.

Comment: What JSON serialization do you use?

Comment: "JSON" does not perform any escaping - your JSON library does, and you need to tell us which one.

Comment: I'm using org.json.JSONArray. Also, I'm using Java.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it json-simple that you are using? They have an open issue for this, no luck with a fix so far:

https://github.com/fangyidong/json-simple/issues/8

I just hacked their source code.

Comment: No I am using org.json (for an Android app): http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/package-summary.html

Comment: Since there really is no other solution to this problem until they modify the source code themselves, this answer is the most suitable.