# Escape character in JSON parsing with org.json.JSONObject;

Tags: java, json, org.json

I am using org.json to parse and write json. While serializing, i.e converting to string, I see json object adds an extra escape character. How can be this be avoided, if possible ?

```
  String jsonStr = "{\"AD\":\"</p>\"}";

  JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(jsonStr);
  System.out.println(jsonStr);
  System.out.println(jsonObject.toString());
```

Output:

```
{"AD":"</p>"}
{"AD":"<\/p>"}
```

Comment: Why are you worried about this? Take the String it produces and try to create a `JSONObject` from it. It will work correctly. You shouldn't be parsing JSON without a parser/generator anyway.

Comment: I am dumping back this string to another file. These file now are different.

Comment: Then just dump the original string...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Making JSON not Escape Forward Slashes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6011012/making-json-not-escape-forward-slashes)

Answer (score 0):

A number of other StackOverflow posts point out that this happens because (1) it is allowed by the JSON spec, and (2) it allows the JSON string to be inserted as-is into certain XML/HTML contexts that would otherwise not allow strings with `"</"` inside them.

If this causes problems, I would seek out [A Better Java JSON Library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/338586/a-better-java-json-library)--one that lets you define more character-escaping options.