# replace string of php response

Tags: php, json, response

i am having php file like this..

```
<?php

        define('HOST','localhost');
        define('USER','root');
        define('PASS','123');
        define('DB','123');

        $mysqli = new mysqli(HOST,USER,PASS,DB);
        /* check connection */
        if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
        printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
        exit();
        }       

        $mysqli->query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");
        //$sql="SELECT via,events,doc FROM profile";
                $sql="SELECT via, doc FROM profile";
        $result=$mysqli->query($sql);
        while($e=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
        $output["response"][]=$e;

        //json_encode($output) = str_replace("\/", '/', json_encode($output));/* not working*/
        }   

        echo(json_encode($output)); 
        $mysqli->close();   

        ?>
```

it is giving response like this.

```
{"response":[{"via":"19156001882722","doc":"http:\/\/oursite\/propic_uploads\/58.png"},{"via":"sunil holla","doc":"propic_uploads\/Fantasia Painting(29).jpg"}]}
```

how can i get the above response like this.I mean how to replace the above response with this one.

```
{"response":[{"via":"19156001882722","doc":"http://oursite/propic_uploads/58.png"},{"via":"sunil holla","doc":"propic_uploads/Fantasia Painting(29).jpg"}]}
```

can anyone please help me to get this...

Comment: how is it stored in your db?

Comment: Why do you want this? The '\' characters are there to escape the '/' characters. It tells a parser that the next character is not syntax, and should be interpreted as a normal character.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Already solved here: [json_encode() escaping forward slashes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10210338/json-encode-escaping-forward-slashes)

You only need to use the JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES flag:

`json_encode($str, JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES);`

Comment: ohh very cool solution, good work than to me.. vote for u

Comment: simple and good. thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to [stripslashes()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.stripslashes.php) function for strip slashes from your response.

**Example:**

```
$string = '{"response":[{"via":"19156001882722","doc":"http:\/\/oursite\/propic_uploads\/58.png"},{"via":"sunil holla","doc":"propic_uploads\/Fantasia Painting(29).jpg"}]}';    
echo stripslashes($string);
```

**Result:**

```
{"response":[{"via":"19156001882722","doc":"http://oursite/propic_uploads/58.png"},{"via":"sunil holla","doc":"propic_uploads/Fantasia Painting(29).jpg"}]}
```