# Clean up Json URL data

Tags: php, jquery, json, regex

I have the  following function that generates data for me :

```
 function get_project_time() {
        $name;
        $desc;
        $values;
        $to;
        $from;
        $sql = $this->db->query("Select * from tbl_project")->result();
        foreach ($sql as $value) {

            $name = $value->project_name;
            $desc = $value->project_status;
            $start_date = $value->start_date;
            $end_date = $value->end_date;
            $unix_start_date = strtotime($start_date);
            $unix_end_date = strtotime($end_date);
            $to = "Date($unix_start_date)/";
            $from = "Date($unix_end_date)/";
            $e = new stdClass();
            $f = new stdClass();
            $e->name = $name;
            $e->desc = $desc;
            $f->to = $to;
            $f->from = $from;
            $e->values = array($f);

            echo json_encode(array($e));
        }
    }
```

The json output looks in the  following format :

```
[{"name":"e-Campus and eLearning Project","desc":"in_progress","values":[{"to":"\/Date(1473627600)\/","from":"\/Date(1480626000)\/"}]}][{"name":"BloodLink Training Project","desc":"in_progress","values":[{"to":"\/Date(1474405200)\/","from":"\/Date(1475010000)\/"}]}][{"name":"Test Project","desc":"","values":[{"to":"\/Date(1474405200)\/","from":"\/Date(1475182800)\/"}]}]
```

I would like to clean up the  data so that I get something like this :

```
[{"name":"e-Campus and eLearning Project","desc":"in_progress","values":[{"to":"/Date(1473627600)/","from":"/Date(1480626000)/"}]}][{"name":"BloodLink Training Project","desc":"in_progress","values":[{"to":"/Date(1474405200)/","from":"/Date(1475010000)/"}]}][{"name":"Test Project","desc":"","values":[{"to":"/Date(1474405200)/","from":"/Date(1475182800)/"}]}]
```

Please advise on how I can clean the  json Data ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10210338/json-encode-escaping-forward-slashes

Comment: You're doing it wrong. You're doing `echo json_encode(..)` INSIDE your loop, so you're producing multiple independent json strings. You need to build an array/object inside the loop. You only encode at the END of the process, when the building is done.

Answer (score 0):

Most of that code is redundant/useless. You could trivially save yourself a lot
of lines with something like this:

```
$sql = "SELECT project_name AS name, ... UNIX_TIMESTAMP(end_date) AS end_date etc...";

while($row = fetch()) {
   $array[] = $row;
}

echo json_encode($array);
```

Building an object, just so you can typecast it to an array, is utterly wasteful and confusing. If you want an array, then build an array. Done do "Give me a bigmac with extra lettuce" and then convert it to a filet 'o fish afterwards.