# How to remove escaping special characters from json_encode output

Tags: php, json

I have some URLs in my database, and I want to print them as JSON using PHP. How can I get the desired format, without escaping backslashes, in my JSON object?

```
// Business to get data
...
// print JSON data
echo json_encode($customer, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
```

[image]

Comment: i think extra spaces are added n you want to remove that?

Comment: What's in the variable $customer?

Comment: This sounds like a typical xy problem. Why would you want to print the json unescaped? Javascript have a command for consuming JSON, it's called JSON.parse, and it allows you to use json and transform it into javascript objects.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [json\_encode() escaping forward slashes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10210338/json-encode-escaping-forward-slashes)

Comment: hi @FélixGagnon-Grenier i will consume the json output in Android Project using java , i will not use javascript as a client

Comment: @Ali then use Java way to parse JSON http://stackoverflow.com/a/18998203/576767.

Answer (score 16):

This sounds like a typical [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). There are very few situations where you would want to unescape JSON (and I say this to be polite, I can't think of a single one) and in your case, your code suggests you echo that JSON so it can be consumed elsewhere.

*Elsewhere* probably means on a client with JavaScript. There is the [JSON.parse](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) function that does exactly what you want, and more: it transforms JSON (correct JSON, that still has its escaping backslashes) into native JavaScript object.

```
echo json_encode(["url" => "http://stackoverflow.com"]);
// {"url":"http:\/\/stackoverflow.com"}
```

---

```
// out of scope, but response is the response from your ajax call
var parsedJson = JSON.parse(response);
console.log(parsedJson.url);
// http://stackoverflow.com
```

This is how you actually get your unescaped string from JSON.