# Convert data from json into an array

Tags: php, json

I receive data from an api and I would like to convert value of "game" into an array of array.

I tried

```
$data = json_decode($json, true);
$array = $data['data']['game'];
```

It gives me a string.

Here is the data.

```
{"data":{"game":"[[\"1\",\"1\",\"0\",\"0\",\"0\",\"1\",\"1\",\"0\",\"0\",\"0\",\"0\",\"1\",\"1\",\"1\",\"0\",\"0\",\"1\",\"1\",\"1\",\"0\",\"0\",\"0\",\"1\",\"0\",\"0\",\"0\",\"0\",\"0\",\"0\",\"1\",\"0\",\"0\",\"0\",\"0\",\"1\",\"1\",\"0\",\"0\",\"0\",\"0\",\"1\",\"1\",\"1\",\"0\",\"0\",\"0\",\"0\",\"0\",\"1\",\"0\",\"0\",\"0\",\"0\",\"0\",\"0\",\"0\",\"0\",\"0\",\"0\",\"0\",\"0\",\"0\",\"0\",\"0\",\"1\",\"0\",\"0\",\"0\",\"0\",\"0\",\"0\",\"1\",\"1\"],[\"0\",\"0\",\"0\",\"0\",\"1\",\"0\",\"0\",\"0\",\"0\",\"1\",\"0\",\"1\",\"0\",\"0\",\"0\",\"0\",\"1\",\"1\",\"0\",\"0\",\"0\",\"1\",\"1\",\"0\",\"1\",\"0\",\"0\",\"0\",\"0\",\"1\",\"1\",\"0\",\"0\",\"0\",\"0\",\"0\",\"0\",\"0\",\"0\",\"0\",\"0\",\"1\",\"0\",\"0\",\"0\",\"1\",\"1\",\"0\",\"1\",\"0\",\"0\",\"0\",\"0\",\"1\",\"1\",\"0\",\"0\",\"1\",\"1\",\"0\",\"0\",\"0\",\"0\",\"1\",\"1\",\"0\",\"1\",\"0\",\"0\",\"1\",\"1\",\"0\",\"1\"]]"},
"status":200}
```

Thank you.

Comment: That's not an array, it's an actual string. You should `json_decode($array)`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [json\_encode() escaping forward slashes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10210338/json-encode-escaping-forward-slashes)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this will work

```
<?php

$json = '{"data":{"game":"[[\"1\",\"1\",\"0\",\"0\",\"0\",\"1\",\"1\",\"0\",\"0\",\"0\",\"0\",\"1\",\"1\",\"1\",\"0\",\"0\",\"1\",\"1\",\"1\",\"0\",\"0\",\"0\",\"1\",\"0\",\"0\",\"0\",\"0\",\"0\",\"0\",\"1\",\"0\",\"0\",\"0\",\"0\",\"1\",\"1\",\"0\",\"0\",\"0\",\"0\",\"1\",\"1\",\"1\",\"0\",\"0\",\"0\",\"0\",\"0\",\"1\",\"0\",\"0\",\"0\",\"0\",\"0\",\"0\",\"0\",\"0\",\"0\",\"0\",\"0\",\"0\",\"0\",\"0\",\"0\",\"1\",\"0\",\"0\",\"0\",\"0\",\"0\",\"0\",\"1\",\"1\"],[\"0\",\"0\",\"0\",\"0\",\"1\",\"0\",\"0\",\"0\",\"0\",\"1\",\"0\",\"1\",\"0\",\"0\",\"0\",\"0\",\"1\",\"1\",\"0\",\"0\",\"0\",\"1\",\"1\",\"0\",\"1\",\"0\",\"0\",\"0\",\"0\",\"1\",\"1\",\"0\",\"0\",\"0\",\"0\",\"0\",\"0\",\"0\",\"0\",\"0\",\"0\",\"1\",\"0\",\"0\",\"0\",\"1\",\"1\",\"0\",\"1\",\"0\",\"0\",\"0\",\"0\",\"1\",\"1\",\"0\",\"0\",\"1\",\"1\",\"0\",\"0\",\"0\",\"0\",\"1\",\"1\",\"0\",\"1\",\"0\",\"0\",\"1\",\"1\",\"0\",\"1\"]]"},
"status":200}';

$array = json_decode($json, true);
$array = json_decode($array['data']['game'], true);


echo '<pre>';
print_r($array);
```