# Slashes in php variable not being parsed correctly in javascript

Tags: php, javascript, json

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [JSON: why are forward slashes escaped?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1580647/json-why-are-forward-slashes-escaped)

I am passing values which contain `"//"` from *PHP to Javascript*. However the values keep parsing `"//"` as: `"\/\/"` when I decode using json, no matter how I try to enclose or escape the strings... .

Here's the code I'm using:

**PHP**

```
foreach($varr as $vr)
{
    array_push($legendarr, "%%.%% - ".$vr);                        
    array_push($linkarr, "http://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']."/getdata.php?criteria=".$vr);
}
```

**JavaScript:**

```
pie = r.piechart(320, 240, 100, <?php echo json_encode($vcr); ?>, { legend: <?php echo json_encode($legendarr); ?>, legendpos: "west", href: <?php echo json_encode($linkarr); ?>});
```

The problem is that the variable `linkarr` is displayed in the form:

> `http:\/\/localhost:8090\/getdata.php?criteria=......`

Could anyone know why this is happening? How can I fix it?

Thanks.

Comment: In PHP5.4+ you could use the `JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES` option. As mentioned it's generally unneeded for JS though. (Also available in upgradephp `up_json_encode()` for earlier PHP versions.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A string `"http:\/\/www.example.org"` will still be printed as `"http://www.example.org"` in JavaScript.

The escaped slashes is, I believe, part of the JSON standard. But it shouldn't affect your JS code in any way.

Btw, the `mysql_escape_string('//')` is completely out of context; HTML != database.

Comment: Oops, that was just a manifestation of frustration... Unfortunately I'm using Raphael.js and it prints the http links incorrectly...

Comment: Just discovered the problem was from somewhere else. Thanks!!