# Why would they write composer.json in 1 line like this?

Tags: composer-php

Not sure if I understand the point of writing .json config in a single line like this with both forward and backwards slashes?:

```
{"name":"zendframework\/zendservice-twitter","description":"OOP wrapper for the Twitter web service","type":"library","keywords":["zf2","twitter"],"homepage":"http:\/\/packages.zendframework.com\/","license":"BSD-3-Clause","autoload":{"psr-0":{"ZendService":"library\/"}},"repositories":[{"type":"composer","url":"http:\/\/packages.zendframework.com\/"}],"require":{"php":">=5.3.3","zendframework\/zend-http":">=2.0.0","zendframework\/zend-uri":">=2.0.0","zendframework\/zend-version":">=2.0.0"},"extra":{"branch-alias":{"dev-master":"2.0.x-dev"}},"version":"2.0.1","dist":{"url":"http:\/\/packages.zendframework.com\/composer\/ZendService_Twitter-2.0.1.zip","type":"zip"}}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The backslash `\` is an escape character, so every time you see `\/`, the `/` is being escaped.

The fact that the entire object is written on one line is most likely an artifact of whatever generated the JSON (I'm assuming it was not handwritten).

Comment: I believe `/` doesn't need escaping.

Comment: The question seems to be _why_ is it escaped and a one-liner.

Comment: @JanDvorak I would think if that were the case OP would have asked "why are forward slashes escaped," not "why are there both forward and backward slashes"

Comment: they seem to escape forward slashes here. And this answer here clarifies  that it's not really required: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1580647/json-why-are-forward-slashes-escaped ..... Still not sure about 1 line??? windows/linux compatibility?

Comment: @RyanEckert I was just about to add that link to my answer - It looks like PHP's json encoding implementation does it. The fact that it's on one line is likely an artifact of the same encoding function.

Comment: yeah. imho  - you right. Since it autolatically generated it would make sense not to include PHP_EOL, since it's unknown at that that what platform this will be used on.