# How to make JSONWriter XML safe?

Tags: java, xml, json

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [JSON: why are forward slashes escaped?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1580647/json-why-are-forward-slashes-escaped)

Using `org.json.JSONWriter` in Java, if I include XML values, the closing tags show up escaped. For example:

```
<version>2.0<\/version>
```

Comment: What is your question? What is your input/code/desired output? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: What makes you think it's *not* safe ? i.e. what happens if you read that JSON back ? Do you get the XML returned intact (clue: yes)

Comment: The sample I posted shows it's not "safe" ie, incorrect. Every closing tag has a \ character in it.