# JSON/Jettison wrong format in string started with / (slash)

Tags: java, json

I want this JSON:

```
{"lala":{"any":1,"/doc/h2":1}}
```

But using Jetisson ( http://jettison.codehaus.org/ ) like the example below:

```
  JSONObject extractJson = new JSONObject();
  int i = 1;

  extractJson.put("lala", new JSONObject()
      .put("any",1)
      .put("/doc/h" + (i+1), 1)  # HERE!
    );

  System.out.println(extractJson.toString());
```

return this:

```
 {"lala":{"any":1,"\/doc\/h2":1}}
```

with an extra '\' in front of any '/'

My question is: why? How I can generate the correct json?

Any Idea?

Answer (score 0):

It looks likt your library (jettison) escapes slashed by default. This is OK for json and any parser should be able to un-escape them again when parsing.

Apparantly, according to [JSON: why are forward slashes escaped?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1580647/json-why-are-forward-slashes-escaped) it is because of HTML and specifically script-tags.

If you really don't want them there you have a couple of options:

- look into your library documentation on how to not escape by default.
- change library.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the option of switching libraries, [GSON](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) can do this with ease:

```
JsonObject jsonObj = new JsonObject();
jsonObj.addProperty("field1", 5);
jsonObj.addProperty("/doc/h2", 1);
System.out.println(jsonObj.toString());
```