# JSONObject.toString: how NOT to escape slashes

Tags: java, android, json

I need to send a date in JSON. The date string should look like this:

> "2013/5/15"

Instead , `JSONObject.toString` escapes it as follows:

> "2013\ /5\ /15"

I understand that this is done to allow json strings inside scripts tags, as this question explains:
[JSON: why are forward slashes escaped?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1580647/813951)

But in my case I don't need it. In fact the server is returning an error. The server is not dealing with this and I can't fix the server, so I must fix it in the mobile client code.

I could do a `String.replace` after serializing it, but what if I actually wanted to include the "\ /" string in any other part of the JSON?

Is there a way to serialize a JSON object without escaping slashes? (If possible, without escaping anything)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I finally opted for the quick and dirty trick of replacing the escaped slashes in the serialized string before sending it to the server. Luckily, JSONObject also escapes backslashes, so i must also unscape them. Now if I wanted to send "\ /" intentionally the escaped string would be "\\/" and the result of replacing is the original string as intended.

Comment: It's very weird how this is still happening!!
Anywho, I did a String replace on the json string and got the resulting string and passed that to the StringEntity. It worked like magic. Thanks and cheers!!

Comment: My gess is: `json.replace("\\\\", "\\")`

Answer (score 7):

```
jsonObjSend.toString().replace("\\\\","")
```

Worked for me. A bit dirty trick but seems no other solution.

Comment: `jsonObjSend.toString().replace("\\","") ` didn't work for me but `jsonObjSend.toString().replace("\\\\","") ` worked. What can be the reason?

Comment: Shouldn't be `jsonObject.toString().replace("\\/","/")` ???

Answer (score 6):

That behavior is hard-coded into [JSONStringer.java](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/libcore/+/android-4.2.2_r1/json/src/main/java/org/json/JSONStringer.java), see method `private void string(String value)`, line 302+.

It should be possible to copy class `JSONStringer` and implement your own version of `value(Object)` (line 227+). Then implement your own version of [JSONObject](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/libcore/+/android-4.2.2_r1/json/src/main/java/org/json/JSONObject.java).toString() in a utility class and use your own JSONStringer instead of the original.

EDIT: Subclassing JSONStringer won't be easy because value() calls a private method beforeValue() that cannot be accessed.

Comment: Maybe another JSON library will also do what you want, see [google-gson](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) for example.

Comment: You are right. The `JsonWriter.setHtmlSafe` method seems to do exactly that. The default setting is false, so I guess this library produces unscaped JSON strings. I don't have the time to test it, but if you did I'd accept this as solution :)

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar problem with JSONObject "put" when dealing with data for an image that was encoded into a adat  Uri "data:image/png;base64,.....". The put function would add another slash to change the format to "data:image/png;base64,.....". It seems that the source of the problem is a string value check within the JSONObject "put" function that adds the extra slashs. One could maybe overload the function or extend the class but I found the easiest way is to add a unique string such as guid and then replace that guid with your Uri string after the calling the toString() function of your JSONObject.

```
JSONObject userJson = new JSONObject(); 
String myimageUri = "data:image/png;base64,XXXDATAXXX";
userJson.put("imageUri", "b0c8f13d-48b1-46b4-af28-4e2d8004a6f8");
userJson.toString().replace("b0c8f13d-48b1-46b4-af28-4e2d8004a6f8", myimageUri);
```

Answer (score 0):

I was getting similar slashes when I used

```
val dateString = Gson().toJson(dateObject).toString()
```

You need to deserialize this json.

```
JSONObject(dateString)
```

Answer (score -5):

The problem is with the imports.

Use below imports :-

```
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;
```

Instead of `import org.json.simple.JSONObject;`

It will work.

[image: See image]

Comment: Hm, no, I'm definitely importing `org.json.JSONObject` and not the "simple" variant, and I have these dumb escaped slashes. :(