# JSON object adding extra back slash

Tags: java, json, backslash

What i am doing currently creating json object and passing to volley for service call, its placing back slash in jsonObject in key value result is getting 404. following is my code and creating jsonObject.

```
 JSONObject params = new JSONObject();
 params.put("user_name", "syedshah11@gmail.com");
 params.put("password", "6e7a0497daffa4554cc28973bc129632");
 params.put("key", "ly9jCDu03/1:3M1");
```

And as i debuged the josnObject adding extra \ (forward slash in my key json object thats why service break through as 404)   following is json getting through debug.

```
{
  "password": "6e7a0497daffa4554cc28973bc129632",
  "user_name": "syedshah11@gmail.com",
  "key": "ly9jCDu03\/1:3M1"
}
```

So how to remove this \ extra forward slash as instead of this `ly9jCDu03/1:3M1` its making `ly9jCDu03\/1:3M1`    any help could be appreciated.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: FWIW, it's harmless. In JSON (as in JavaScript), within a string literal, `\/` means `/`. More: http://json.org/ The actual string represented does not have the backslash in it.

Comment: *"...forward slash in my key json object thats why service break through as 404..."* Then the service is broken, and that's what needs fixing. The JSON is entirely valid.

Comment: but i m getting 404 on reponse, while its working fine in postman, what the solution for this. @T.J.Crowder

Comment: Fix the thing that's breaking on perfectly valid JSON.

Comment: (BTW: You'll want to update the question to say what JSON library you're using, as there are several, probably at least two with `JSONObject`.)

Comment: Please, tell how and where you use this jsonobject or/and its values. Because there is something wrong in other part of you code, this json is correct.

Comment: By putting this value in postman ly9jCDu03\/1:3M1 getting 404 in postman @maximelian1986

Comment: I know issue is with this ly9jCDu03\/1:3M1

Comment: what the hell is this why down vote ???

Comment: Four ppl told you that with given code this value from json perspective looks ok. So pls provide us more information, because we can not guess how you tring to use it so we can't spot any mistakes and give you any suggestion.

Comment: May be this will help you somehow http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16563579/jsonobject-tostring-how-not-to-escape-slashes

Comment: already tied but did not work out @maximelian1986

Answer (score 1):

Java is encoding your JSON string for sending to end point. Slash (/) is not an issue, if request not build with proper manners and there is any problem at Java end then you receive 500 Internal Server Error or volley error.

Be confident on your code and check service.

Answer (score 1):

when json convert key value to string "ly9jCDu03/1:3M1" it adds extra '\' to represent the '/' as '/' is a special character and to represent that u need '\'

it is just like when u want to print '/n' in c++ u need to add extra '\'