# How to remove backword slashes from date of birth string in android

Tags: java, android

I am posting data from registration form to server using Asynctask method in json format.

I am getting the Date of Birth from calendar in **04/13/2018** format. But after converting this in to json format it is showing like this : **04/\13/\2018**.

I have tried `replace("\\" "")` and `replaceAll("\\\\" ,"")` functions for removing the backslash from the string but no luck. Here is my code.

```
            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
            String fomattedDate = "04/13/2018";
            Log.e("DOB", formattedDate);
          //Here it is printing like normal format, i.e; 04/13/2018

            formattedDate = mSelctedDate.replace("\\", "");

            jsonObject.accumulate("DateOfBirth", formattedDate);

            String json = jsonObject.toString();
```

But here it is printing like

```
{"DateOfBirth":"04/\13/\2018"}
```

Please any one help me to sort out this issue.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JSONObject.toString: how NOT to escape slashes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16563579/jsonobject-tostring-how-not-to-escape-slashes)?

Comment: have you tried replacing after converting the json object to string?

Comment: Thank You @MaxG.

Comment: Thank You @OleV.V.