# Why does MySQL database return backslashes for forward slashes

Tags: php, mysql, json

I entered urls into a MySQL db and when I log it out as json /php I get this:

```
http:\/\/www.etc....
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 4):

JSON escapes `/` as `\/` - this is because older browser JavaScript need to use `eval` to parse it, and many old browsers would use `</` to mark the end of a JavaScript block. Therefore, `\/` makes it safe.

Comment: Thanks.  How do I fix it so I can get the no-forward-slashes version? How do I parse it?

Comment: You would need to pass `JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES` as the second argument to `json_encode`. Note that it shouldn't matter, really, since if you're using `json_encode` then the decoding context will remove the backslashes anyway.

Answer (score 2):

This has nothing to do with MySQL, but is the JSON-encoding of your slashes.

See also:  [JSON: why are forward slashes escaped?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1580647/362536)