# how to encode image url in json?

Tags: php, mysql, json

I am working on web services. i am sending image url in response but it is not coming in right format.I need output like:
"template":"http://localhost/restaurant/admin/images2.jpg"

my code is

```
header('Content-Type: application/json');
include("admin/common/connection.php");
$userId= $_GET['user']; 
if(isset($userId))
{
$select="select * from menu_template_background where user_id='".$userId."'";
$query= mysql_query($select);
$fetch_row= mysql_fetch_array($query);
$url="http://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
$str= strripos($url , "/");
$sub=substr($url,$str);
$replace=str_ireplace($sub,"",$url);

$template=$replace."/admin/".$fetch_row1['template_url'];
$fetchmenuDesign= array("template"=>$template);


echo $menuDesign[]=json_encode($fetchmenuDesign);

}
```

when i am trying to hit the image url it is not working.please help me if there is something wrong in my code.

Comment: `http://localhost/restaurant/admin/images2.jpg` looks like a perfectly valid URL for an image. What format are you *expecting*?

Comment: no it is not coming in this format it is coming like  "template":"http:\/\/localhost\/restaurant\/admin\/images2.jpg"

Comment: i need output http://localhost/restaurant/admin/images2.jpg

Comment: Can you show us the code that uses the JSON generated by this?

Comment: `{"template":"http:\/\/localhost\/restaurant\/admin\/images2.jpg"}` is the perfectly valid JSON encoded form of `array('template' => 'http://localhost/restaurant/admin/images2.jpg')`. There's no problem here.

Comment: i have used this to encode json. json_encode($fetchmenuDesign); i have post my code above.

Comment: but when i am trying to hit the url it is not showing image.

Comment: Since you are JSON *encoding* it, you need to be JSON *decoding* it using a decoder which sticks to the JSON standard. Are you doing that? What are you doing with the JSON afterwards?

Comment: i am just sending response in json for iphone web service.iphone developer required response in json.

Comment: please help me if there is anything wrong.

Comment: There is nothing wrong as far as we can see, that's the point.

Answer (score 1):

PHP's `json_encode`, by default, escapes slashes. [**This is perfectly valid JSON.**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1580647/json-why-are-forward-slashes-escaped)

You can override this (in PHP 5.4+) by doing `json_encode($stuff, JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES)` but this really shouldn't be necessary.