# Appending a TR to Table Not Formatting Correctly

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json

My PHP script is sending back an array:

```
$currentStatus = ( isset( $status ) ) ? "1" : "0";
$html = "<tr><td>" . $email . "</td><td>" . ( ( $status->type == 0 ) ? "View Only" : ( ( $status->type == 1 ) ? "View & Mark" : "View, Mark & Edit" ) ) . "</td><td>Invited</td></tr>";

echo json_encode( array( $html, $currentStatus ) );
```

Then my jquery is appending this to the table:

```
...
success: function( result ) {

   var resultArray = eval( result );

   $( "#myTable tr:last").append( resultArray[0] );
   ...
}
```

Problem is, when it prints, it prints the following extra marks:

```
name@email.com<\/td>    View Only<\/td> Invited<\/td><\/tr>","1"]
```

If I only echo the HTML it appends to table just fine, but I cant do that because I need the $currentStatus back too to do something with it.

Thanks!

Comment: Why are you using `.eval`? What is the result of `console.log(result)` -- can you post it?

Comment: Why are you `eval`ing it?

Comment: @tymeJV I am using .eval because its the only way I know how to access the array... is there a better way?

Comment: Are you getting the result as text if so use `JSON.parse(result)`. If you have set the proper content type in the response header or dataType in ajax settings you should get it as array object itself and you don't have to parse it.

Comment: Post the `result`!!!!!

Comment: @tymeJV console.log shows ["<tr><td>name@email.com<\/td><td>View Only<\/td><td>Invited<\/td><\/tr>","1"]

Comment: It's adding that "\" to the td. So rather than </td> its returning <\/td>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Allowing `\/` helps when embedding JSON in a `<script>` tag, which doesn't allow `</` inside strings. [JSON: why are forward slashes escaped?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1580647/json-why-are-forward-slashes-escaped)

You can set options to `json_encode`:

```
echo json_encode(array( ('<tr><td>test@test.com</td><td>Invited</td></tr>')), JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES| JSON_HEX_TAG);

JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES - available from 5.4.0
JSON_HEX_TAG - from 5.3.0
```

Answer (score 0):

I've played with the result that you add in your comment in the console. 
My code looks like this and it seems to work:

```
var resultArray = ["<tr><td>name@email.com<\/td><td>View Only<\/td><td>Invited<\/td><\/tr>","1"];
var resultStringify = JSON.stringify(resultArray);
var resultParse = JSON.parse(resultStringify);

resultParse //Result: ["<tr><td>name@email.com</td><td>View Only</td><td>Invited</td></tr>", "1"]
```

Trying to figure out why it work by first stringify it and then parse it.