# Why java Path.Separator in JSON file format is switched to \?

Tags: java, javascript, json, separator

I want to put a picture path in a jsonObject and pass it to javascript, in java i do

```
JSONObject assets = new JSONObject();

assets.put("media",PropertyLoader.getStringValue("PICTURE_DIRECTORY") + "/"+leventPhoto.getFile().getName());
```

When i get it in the jsp file in javascript it appears like this:

```
"media":"C:\/Users\/joao\/workspace\/.metadata\/.plugins\/org.eclipse.wst.server.core\/tmp1\/wtpwebapps\/RememberMeServer\/images\/02.jpg"
```

What can i do to make the separator appear well formated inside JSONObject displayed in javascript?

Comment: `\/` is a legal escape in a [JSON](http://json.org/) string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By the time the data has been *read* within Javascript, it will have the appropriate name. This is just an escape sequence, which doesn't change the value of the data. For example, in a Javascript console:

```
var x = "foo\/bar";
var y = "foo/bar";
x == y // true
```

I'm surprised that the forward slashes are being escaped - just `"C:/Users/joao/..."` would work fine - but it shouldn't make any difference to the actual value.

Comment: Whenever it detects a / it adds a \ behind it.

Comment: @JoaoFilipeClementeMartins: Sure, it may well do *in the JSON representation*. But by the time that's been parsed by Javascript, the actual *value* will be correct. Try printing out the value in a Javascript console - you'll see it without the backslashes.

Comment: But the string i showed you is already under <script type="text/javascript"> Do i have to parse anything from JSON to javascript?

Comment: @JoaoFilipeClementeMartins: That's the *source code*, effectively. That source code will be parsed by the Javascript interpreter. It's just an escape sequence. Did you try printing out the value in the console, as I suggested? Or using `alert`, or including the value somewhere in the page? You should care about the *value of the variable*, not the source representation in the JSON.

Comment: with this alert(dataObject.timeline.date[0].asset[0].media); it printed out well but nothing appeared.

Comment: @JoaoFilipeClementeMartins: It's not clear what you mean by "but nothing appeared" - what had you expected to happen, and why? If you're using that as a URL for an image somewhere, were you expecting it to be fetched from the server, or from the user's local disk? If it's from the server, that's not an appropriate URL - and if it's from the local disk, I'd be very concerned about security if that were possible.

Comment: It can be a local path or a URL for a image somewhere. I am using Timeline.js to create a timeline and display media content in it. Alhtough i can't make images, videos and other type of media to appear, right now no errors are being displayed.

Comment: @JoaoFilipeClementeMartins: Well do you expect the browser to be able to read local files from arbitrary places on the file system? I'm not a web developer, but I wouldn't *expect* that to work. Anyway, that's a different matter - the business about the backslashes in the JSON is sorted.

Comment: That's why i already gave you the right answer. thx for your help.

Answer (score 1):

It is just escaping the `/`, it is not changing the string itself.

As to why forward slashes are being escaped, you may want to check out this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1580647/json-why-are-forward-slashes-escaped):

> Allowing / helps when embedding JSON in a  tag, which doesn't allow `<`/ inside strings, like [user] points out.