# Wierd form of encoding in NSURL(inviolves backslashes followed by frontslashes after the "http:)

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, nsstring, nsurl

I have to pass JSON dictionary as POST data to a Webservice. One key involves an Amazon S3 URL string.
The sample request json which works has the URL as....

```
https:\/\/myappbucket.s3.amazonaws.com\/2014230407_102323.jpg?response-content-type=image\/png&Signature=123456%3D&Expires=139756222548&AWSAccessKeyId=ABCDEF
```

Notice the backslashes just before the forwardslashes? I have never seen a URL like that, but thats how I'm supposed to pass it.

I tried

```
stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding
```

and

```
stringByReplacingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding
```

while using `NSASCIIStringEncoding` and `NSUTF8StringEncoding`

Can anyone make sense of this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [JSON: why are forward slashes escaped?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1580647/json-why-are-forward-slashes-escaped).  tl;dr: they escape the forward slashes.  Mildly unnecessary, but good to have for most embedded JSON.

Comment: So what you are saying is the backslashes are not needed?

Comment: JSON doesn't require that you escape slashes like that.  The server may be using them for other purposes, or may be based on a library or language that escapes by default.

Answer (score 1):

if we try to convert url into legal url trough stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding than it adds all percent escapes necessary to convert the receiver into a legal URL string.Uses the given encoding to determine the correct percent escapes.
if we use stringByReplacingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding than it replaces all percent escapes with the matching characters as determined by the given encoding.
mostly to get valid url, we can use NSUTF8StringEncoding to remove backslashes just before the forwardslashes in url.

Comment: It's simply *not possible* to "convert" some improperly encoded URL using `stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding` into a "valid" URL. A URI has several *components*, and each component requires a *different* percent encoding algorithm (see RFC 3968). So, your proposed approach won't work. In fact, a workable and reliable approach is (much) more elaborated. Before iOS 7.0, there was no API which made this simpler. Since iOS 7.0 there is `NSURLComponents`. Have a look! ;)

Answer (score 0):

Generally, you should use a JSON serializer library (e.g. `NSJSONSerialization`) in order to obtain a JSON from a *JSON representation* and not try to create the JSON yourself.

A *JSON representation* is a `NSDictionary` or `NSArray` object containing other *objects* which recursively represent your JSON. Your URL will be represented as a `NSString`.

What you need to do is simply have a valid URL as a `NSString`, properly encoded according [RFC 3968](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986) and assign it the JSON representation, e.g.:

```
NSURL* url = ...;
NSDictionary* jsonObject = @{@"url": [url path]};
```

Now, you can serialize the JSON representation to a JSON:

```
NSError* error;
NSData* jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:jsonObejct 
                                                   options:0 
                                                     error:&error];
```

That's it, and you don't bother how the JSON encoded string looks like (encapsulated in the `NSData` object as a UTF-8 character sequence).

Purposefully, when you POST this JSON, you SHOULD specify a corresponding request header:

`ContentType: application/json`

which lets you just use the JSON data as body data *as is*:

```
[request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
request.HTTPBody = jsonData;
```

Side note: `[url path]` returns a URL as a string according RFC 1808 which is obsoleted by RFC 3968 since January 2005 already. Today, there are newer APIs since iOS 7.0, see `NSURLComponents`.