# Boost: Why write_json changing content

Tags: c++, json, boost

I am trying to read and save a json file. The problem is that when I call `write_json(pt, "newFile.json")` it is changing the content of some fields like:

input:

```
"field1":"path/to/file.txt"
```

is changed to:

```
"field1":"path\/to\/file.txt"
```

Is this a bug? How to fix it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It means it escapes the forward slash. The [JSON](http://www.json.org/) spec says you can escape forward slash, but it's not mandatory. As for the reason, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1580647/json-why-are-forward-slashes-escaped) is a good explanation.