# PHP remove weird backslashes from url

Tags: php, string, strip, backslash

i'm working on a small scraper for fun and when I grab some image urls from certain sites they come back really weird.

For example:

scraped url:

```
https:\/\/cdn1.vox-cdn.com\/thumbor\/zN9XawbQJgFPkuAcA2JEGgqApm8=\/cdn0.vox-cdn.com\/uploads\/chorus_asset\/file\/3700712\/tomorrowland54fdf04f23efb_2040.0.jpg
```

desired url:

```
https://cdn1.vox-cdn.com/thumbor/zN9XawbQJgFPkuAcA2JEGgqApm8=/cdn0.vox-cdn.com/uploads/chorus_asset/file/3700712/tomorrowland54fdf04f23efb_2040.0.jpg
```

it's adding unnecessary backslashes, so that url doesn't work when you follow it, it gives an error.

I tried using the stripslashes function as it seems like that's it's purpose but it didn't work. The url just stayed the same.

(edit) here's the code i'm using to grab urls:

```
function GetImages($page_dom) {
        $found_links = [];

        $images = $page_dom->getElementsByTagName('img');
        foreach ($images as $image) {
            $img_src = $image->getAttribute('src');
            $found_links[] = $img_src;
        }

        return $found_links;
    }
```

Comment: Show your code that's doing the scraping.

Comment: It sounds like you're picking up URLs that are in JSON strings.

Comment: Don't post code in comments, update the question.

Comment: @Barmar and i'm not getting the urls from JSON, but I am outputting the data as JSON, is that the issue?

Comment: Yes, `json_encode` escapes slashes by default. You can disable it with the `JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES` option. See  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1580647/json-why-are-forward-slashes-escaped

Comment: Did you try $url = str_replace('\', '', $url); ?

Comment: But it shouldn't be a problem -- the slashes will be removed when you decode the JSON.

Comment: @AramilRey Why would the OP try that if it's not working ? you're escaping a single quote `'`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When you call `json_encode`, use the `JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES` option to prevent it from escaping slashes.

But this shouldn't really be necessary. If you're outputing JSON, you should be sending it to a program that parses JSON, and the JSON parser will translate `\/` to `/`.

Answer (score 0):

if this is the only pattern you are expecting you can use `str_replace('\/', '/', $url)` You can also use `str_replace(array('\/', '\\'), array('/', '\'), $url)` for more patterns