# AFNetworking sending URL as post parameter

Tags: ios, objective-c, afnetworking-2, nsurlrequest

I am calling an API in which I am sending a `URL` link as a post parameter with it.
But while converting it into JSON data using

```
NSData* jsonData  = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:lParameters options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted error:&error];
```

it adds extra `'\'` character into the link.
and when I log that data string, it logs like

```
data string : {
  "id" : "1",
  "photoLink" : "https:\/\/7.7.100.120:8443\/webresource\/carsevent\/gallery\/approved\/image-a31ea5e0-6284-402a-9e6a-b0cdba37bc1f.png"
}
```

Log :

Dictionary :

```
{
    id = 1;
    photoLink = "https://7.7.100.120:8443/webresource/carsevent/gallery/approved/image-a31ea5e0-6284-402a-9e6a-b0cdba37bc1f.png";
}
```

So API is returning error in this case.
How can I overcome from this?

Any help would be much appreciable.
Thanks

Comment: What error is the API returning, add that to the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JSON must have certain characters escaped with a "\" character and even though "/" is not required to be escaped it is allowed to be escaped. Therefor the JSON with escaped "/" characters is valid and should be accepted by the API.

You can remove them if needed.

```
NSString *jsonString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:jsonData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
jsonString = [jsonString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\\/" withString:@"/"];
jsonData = [jsonString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

File a bug report: http://bugreport.apple.com requesting an option to not escape "/".

See this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1580682/451475).

See [JSON](http://json.org) for the characters that must be escaped.

Comment: Thanks man, you saved lot of my time... +1 for your great explanation.