# URL in JSON object as POST request Android

Tags: java, android, json, post

Please help me to send a JSON object in POST HTTP request through HttpClient, in Android.

The problem I am facing is that the JSON object having the URL is replaced by forward slash ,i.e

originally it should have the following value in JSON object

{"product":
 {"featured_src":"https:\/\/example.com\/wp-content\/uploads\/2015\/06\/sidney-compressed.jpg,
 "short_description":"this is a test","title":"Raiders from the North"}
}

i tried many options to keep it in the above format. But it always comes as {"featured_src": [image]

Comment: your JSON is invalid

Comment: @Arlind can you please help me to help overcome the forward slashes.

Comment: check this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1580647/json-why-are-forward-slashes-escaped

Comment: So just to understand your problem, you want to make your URL looks correct https:\\example.com\wp-content\uploads.... insted \/\/ ?

Comment: @maytham Those are backslashes, URLs should have forward slashes, like http://

Answer (score 0):

We assume this is your input

```
private final static String JSON_DATA = "{"
        + "  \"product\": ["
        + "    {"
        + "      \"featured_src\": \"https:\\/\\/example.com\\/wp-content"
        + "\\/uploads\\/2015\\/06\\/sidney-compressed.jpg\","
        + "      \"short_description\": \"this is a test\","
        + "      \"title\" : \"Raiders from the North\""
        + "    }"
        + "  ]"
        + "}";
```

You could use `replace` to do the trick.

```
YOUR_STRING.replace("\\", "");
```

Finally your method would look like this, by passing your string as parameter

```
private static String jsonUrlCorrector(String json_data) {
    json_data = json_data.replace("\\", "");
    return json_data;
}
```

Here is the input:

```
{"product":[{"featured_src":"https:\/\/example.com\/wp-content\/uploads\/2015\/06\/sidney-compressed.jpg","short_description": "this is a test","title":"Raiders from the North"}]}
```

Here is the output

```
{"product":[{"featured_src":"https://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/06/sidney-compressed.jpg","short_description":"this is a test","title":"Raiders from the North"}]}
```