# Converting object(having url as a property) to json c#

Tags: c#, json, datacontractserializer

I have a this method to serialise objects to json.

```
public string SerialiseObject(object obj)
{
    using (var dataStream = new MemoryStream())
    using (var reader = new StreamReader(dataStream))
    {
        var objSer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(obj.GetType());
        objSer.WriteObject(dataStream, obj);
        dataStream.Position = 0;
        var bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(reader.ReadToEnd());
        return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes);
    }
}
```

It was working fine for all my objects unless I have this new property which holds a url in it.

```
MyObject.StoreUrl = "https://www.myCoffeeShop.com";
```

now when I use my serialize method it generates

```
"StoreUrl": "https:\/\/www.myCoffeeShop.com"
```

while I am expecting

```
"StoreUrl": "https://www.myCoffeeShop.com"
```

Can someone please tell me what am I missing?

Comment: possible duplicate of [JSON: why are forward slashes escaped?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1580647/json-why-are-forward-slashes-escaped)

Comment: `HttpUtility.UrlEncode`

Comment: In the JSON standard, the forward slash character inside a string literal should be escaped in that way.  See http://json.org/.