# Javascript cannot parsing JSON if the data contains some URL

Tags: javascript, json

I have a valid JSON:

```
{"name":"tono","html":"<p><a href=\"http:\/\/someurl.com\">Here<\/a> is the link<\/p>"}
```

But, when I parse it through javascript (I use firefox's console)

```
JSON.parse('{"name":"tono","html":"<p><a href=\"http:\/\/someurl.com\">Here<\/a> is the link<\/p>"}');
```

I get this error

```
SyntaxError: JSON.parse: expected ',' or '}' after property value in object at line 1 column 36 of the JSON data
```

Is it an expected behavior?
And how to parse JSON which contains URL correctly?

Just for additional information, this one works:

```
JSON.parse('{"name":"tono","html":"<p><a href=>Here<\/a> is the link<\/p>"}');

Object { name: "tono", html: "<p><a href=>Here</a> is the link</p>" }
```

More additional information:

The JSON parsed flawlessly here: http://jsonviewer.stack.hu

Comment: You cannot simply put any arbitrary string into JS code and expect it to stay the same: you must encode it properly. Just try to alert `'{"name":"tono","html":"<p><a href=\"http:\/\/someurl.com\">Here<\/a> is the link<\/p>"}'` string and you'll spot the problem.

Comment: You need to escape the backslashes when you use them in a string literal.

Comment: @TravisJ it **is** valid.

Comment: @TravisJ JSONLint say's it's valid.

Comment: (There's no need to backslash-escape the forward slashes.)

Comment: @DavidConrad and the standard allows you to do so.

Comment: @zerkms The standard also allows you to escape each occurrence of the letter e, but there would be no reason to do so.

Comment: [Why are forward slashes escaped](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1580647/json-why-are-forward-slashes-escaped)

Comment: @DavidConrad and your point is? Encoder decided to put a slash before a forward slash. So? Are you suggesting to apply string replace function on over a valid JSON string?

Comment: @Barmar Thanks for that. It's an edge case, certainly, but worth knowing about.

Comment: Why are you putting a JSON string into the source code in the first place? If you're writing Javascript, just put the object literal: `obj = {"name":"tono","html":"<p><a href=\"http:\/\/someurl.com\">Here<\/a> is the link<\/p>"};`

Comment: I don't say I put it on the source code. Actually I was trying to parse PHP's response from AJAX.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Escape the backslashes in a string literal so they'll be treated literally.

```js
console.log(JSON.parse('{"name":"tono","html":"<p><a href=\\"http:\\/\\/someurl.com\\">Here<\\/a> is the link<\\/p>"}'));
```

The reason why the forward slashes are escaped is explained here [JSON: why are forward slashes escaped?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1580647/json-why-are-forward-slashes-escaped)

Comment: I updated the answer to add a link to the reason for the redundant escapes

Comment: It may be redundant, but it works :) And the URL is worth to read.

Answer (score -2):

As Barmar explained, you can escape the backslashes like such.

```js
JSON.parse('{"name":"tono","html":"<p><a href=\\"http://someurl.com\\">Here</a> is the link</p>"}');
```

Comment: barmar explained it, so why are you?

Comment: Look: http://jsfiddle.net/yjedwLws/ you will see what's wrong. it completey messes up the url.

Comment: @Pamblam I don't see anything wrong with the output. Are you sure you understand what `JSON.stringify` does?