# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL - A simple string syntactically wrong

Tags: javascript, string, variables

Why this seemingly simple string variable is syntactically wrong?

```
var str = "<script>functionName()</script>";
```

I am getting the following error

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL

here is the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ou48kya1/)

Comment: [`var str = "<script>functionName()<\/script>";`](https://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/ou48kya1/1/)

Comment: Does this only happen in jsfiddle?

Comment: @Tushar I have tried this is in fiddle and in console. In console it works fine. In fiddle it gives this problem. I am trying to understand why it is happening.

Comment: The problem is explained by GokulShrinivas, it's because of `CDATA` added by fiddle

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open the console and try putting the string

`var str = "<script>functionName()</script>";`

There are no syntax errors and everything works fine.

When you are embedding the code in a script tag, like so

```
<script>
// code here
</script>
```

In JSFiddle, if you check the error you will see something like

```
<script type='text/javascript'>//<![CDATA[
window.onload=function(){
var str = "<script>functionName()</script>";
}//]]> 

</script>
```

The Browser does not allow `</` characters in a string when you are embedding it in a `<script>` tag.

So, you'll need to escape it with a `\`

Answer (score 1):

This should work. Added a backslash **"</script>"**.

```
<script>
    var str = "<script>functionName()<\/script>";
</script>
```

Comment: The backslash is needed to escape the next character `/`

Comment: @GokulSrinivas Try `"/s"` in console, not needed.

Comment: This will help you understanding escaping forward slashes

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1580647/json-why-are-forward-slashes-escaped

Comment: @Tushar Please try the string `var str = "<script>functionName()</script>";` in the console too. You will not get any error. The problem comes when you try to embed it in a script tag.