# \/\/ in src URL

Tags: javascript, facebook, url, src

I can't find a way to google this answer, and I'm not sure what the best title for this question would be either.
If you go to a video on facebook, such as 
https://www.facebook.com/sari.electronplus/videos/10208501562556645/

and you look at the source, there are all these lines with url's

```js
{"type":"js","src":"https:\/\/www.facebook.com\/rsrc.php\/v3ixjD4\/yL\/l\/en_US\/WwzFPTYi5Xh.js?_nc_srcc=2665","crossOrigin":1},"CDaAd":
```

For what reason are there "/"s instead of "/" in the link?

Comment: It is JSON encoding. Just JSON decode what you get from Facebook

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It helps when embedding in a script tag which doesn't allow certain characters.

See this answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/1580682/1927618