# Running composer update changes format of composer.json

Tags: php, composer-php

I am not certain if this is expected behavior, composer.json is modified as 
 escaped json after running composer install.

My initial composer.json:

```
{
    "name": "digitalstate/platform-application",
    "description": "DigitalState Platform Application",
    "homepage": "https://github.com/DigitalState/Platform-Application.git",
    "keywords": ["DigitalState"],
    "license": "MIT",
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "": "src/"
        }
    },
    "repositories": {
        "composer": {
            "type": "composer",
            "url": "https://packagist.orocrm.com"
        },
        "dsplatform": {
            "type": "vcs",
            "url": "git@bitbucket.org:villemontreal/dsplatform.git"
        }
    },
    "require": {
        "oro/platform": "2.0.5",
        "oro/platform-serialised-fields": "2.0.2",
        "knplabs/knp-time-bundle": "dev-master#272b9d6c127db1a648d2729bc821f0ed19a274d4",
        "craue/formflow-bundle": "dev-master#47b2b7af9b4385f97470ecb858f3a9c03e431587",
        "digitalstate/bpm-camunda-sdk": "dev-master",
        "lexik/jwt-authentication-bundle": "^2.2",
        "mandrill/mandrill": "^1.0",
        "aws/aws-sdk-php": "^3.28",
        "dunglas/doctrine-json-odm": " dev-master",
        "ramsey/uuid": "^3.6"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "sensio/generator-bundle": "3.1.2",
        "behat/behat": "3.2.2",
        "behat/mink-extension": "2.2.*",
        "behat/mink-selenium2-driver": "1.*",
        "behat/symfony2-extension": "2.1.1",
        "nelmio/alice": "2.2.*",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "5.7.*",
        "phpunit/phpunit-selenium": "3.0.*",
        "johnkary/phpunit-speedtrap": "1.0.*",
        "mybuilder/phpunit-accelerator": "1.2.*",
        "squizlabs/php_codesniffer": "2.7.*",
        "phpmd/phpmd": "2.5.*",
        "sebastian/phpcpd": "2.0.*",
        "leaphub/phpcs-symfony2-standard": "~2.0.0",
        "league/factory-muffin": "^3.0",
        "league/factory-muffin-faker": "^2.0",
        "codeception/codeception": "^2.2",
        "phploc/phploc": "^3.0"
    },
    "config": {
        "component-dir": "web/bundles/components",
        "bin-dir": "bin"
    },
    "scripts": {
        "post-install-cmd": [
            "Oro\\Bundle\\InstallerBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::checkComposerPlugin",
            "Incenteev\\ParameterHandler\\ScriptHandler::buildParameters",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::buildBootstrap",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installRequirementsFile",
            "Oro\\Bundle\\InstallerBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::setPermissions",
            "Oro\\Bundle\\InstallerBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installAssets",
            "Oro\\Bundle\\InstallerBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::setAssetsVersion"
        ],
        "post-update-cmd": [
            "Oro\\Bundle\\InstallerBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::checkComposerPlugin",
            "Incenteev\\ParameterHandler\\ScriptHandler::buildParameters",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::buildBootstrap",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installRequirementsFile",
            "Oro\\Bundle\\InstallerBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::setPermissions",
            "Oro\\Bundle\\InstallerBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installAssets",
            "Oro\\Bundle\\InstallerBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::setAssetsVersion"
        ]
    },
    "minimum-stability": "dev",
    "prefer-stable": true,
    "extra": {
        "symfony-app-dir": "app",
        "symfony-web-dir": "web",
        "incenteev-parameters": {
            "env-map": {
                "server": "SERVER",
                "database_host": "APP_DB_HOST",
                "database_user": "APP_DB_USER",
                "database_password": "APP_DB_PASSWORD",
                "database_name": "APP_DB_NAME"
            },
            "file": "app/config/parameters.yml"
        },
        "asset-installer-paths": {
            "npm-asset-library": "web/bundles/npmassets",
            "bower-asset-library": "web/bundles/bowerassets"
        }
    }
}
```

Output of composer.json after running composer install:

```
{
    "name": "digitalstate\/platform-application",
    "description": "DigitalState Platform Application",
    "homepage": "https:\/\/github.com\/DigitalState\/Platform-Application.git",
    "keywords": [
        "DigitalState"
    ],
    "license": "MIT",
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "": "src\/"
        }
    },
    "repositories": {
        "composer": {
            "type": "composer",
            "url": "https:\/\/packagist.orocrm.com"
        },
        "dsplatform": {
            "type": "vcs",
            "url": "git@bitbucket.org:villemontreal\/dsplatform.git"
        }
    },
    "require": {
        "oro\/platform": "2.0.5",
        "oro\/platform-serialised-fields": "2.0.2",
        "knplabs\/knp-time-bundle": "dev-master#272b9d6c127db1a648d2729bc821f0ed19a274d4",
        "craue\/formflow-bundle": "dev-master#47b2b7af9b4385f97470ecb858f3a9c03e431587",
        "digitalstate\/bpm-camunda-sdk": "dev-master",
        "lexik\/jwt-authentication-bundle": "^2.2",
        "mandrill\/mandrill": "^1.0",
        "aws\/aws-sdk-php": "^3.28",
        "dunglas\/doctrine-json-odm": " dev-master",
        "ramsey\/uuid": "^3.6"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "sensio\/generator-bundle": "3.1.2",
        "behat\/behat": "3.2.2",
        "behat\/mink-extension": "2.2.*",
        "behat\/mink-selenium2-driver": "1.*",
        "behat\/symfony2-extension": "2.1.1",
        "nelmio\/alice": "2.2.*",
        "phpunit\/phpunit": "5.7.*",
        "phpunit\/phpunit-selenium": "3.0.*",
        "johnkary\/phpunit-speedtrap": "1.0.*",
        "mybuilder\/phpunit-accelerator": "1.2.*",
        "squizlabs\/php_codesniffer": "2.7.*",
        "phpmd\/phpmd": "2.5.*",
        "sebastian\/phpcpd": "2.0.*",
        "leaphub\/phpcs-symfony2-standard": "~2.0.0",
        "league\/factory-muffin": "^3.0",
        "league\/factory-muffin-faker": "^2.0",
        "codeception\/codeception": "^2.2",
        "phploc\/phploc": "^3.0"
    },
    "config": {
        "component-dir": "web\/bundles\/components",
        "bin-dir": "bin"
    },
    "scripts": {
        "post-install-cmd": [
            "Oro\\Bundle\\InstallerBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::checkComposerPlugin",
            "Incenteev\\ParameterHandler\\ScriptHandler::buildParameters",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::buildBootstrap",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installRequirementsFile",
            "Oro\\Bundle\\InstallerBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::setPermissions",
            "Oro\\Bundle\\InstallerBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installAssets",
            "Oro\\Bundle\\InstallerBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::setAssetsVersion"
        ],
        "post-update-cmd": [
            "Oro\\Bundle\\InstallerBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::checkComposerPlugin",
            "Incenteev\\ParameterHandler\\ScriptHandler::buildParameters",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::buildBootstrap",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installRequirementsFile",
            "Oro\\Bundle\\InstallerBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::setPermissions",
            "Oro\\Bundle\\InstallerBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installAssets",
            "Oro\\Bundle\\InstallerBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::setAssetsVersion"
        ]
    },
    "minimum-stability": "dev",
    "prefer-stable": true,
    "extra": {
        "symfony-app-dir": "app",
        "symfony-web-dir": "web",
        "incenteev-parameters": {
            "env-map": {
                "database_driver": "APP_DB_DRIVER",
                "database_host": "APP_DB_HOST",
                "database_port": "APP_DB_PORT",
                "database_name": "APP_DB_NAME",
                "database_user": "APP_DB_USER",
                "database_password": "APP_DB_PASSWORD",
                "mailer_transport": "APP_MAILER_TRANSPORT",
                "mailer_host": "APP_MAILER_HOST",
                "mailer_port": "APP_MAILER_PORT",
                "mailer_encryption": "APP_MAILER_ENCRYPTION",
                "mailer_user": "APP_MAILER_USER",
                "mailer_password": "APP_MAILER_PASSWORD",
                "websocket_bind_port": "APP_WEBSOCKET_BACKEND_PORT",
                "websocket_backend_port": "APP_WEBSOCKET_BACKEND_PORT",
                "websocket_frontend_port": "APP_WEBSOCKET_FRONTEND_PORT",
                "installed": "APP_IS_INSTALLED",
                "secret": "APP_SECRET"
            },
            "file": "app\/config\/parameters.yml"
        },
        "asset-installer-paths": {
            "npm-asset-library": "web\/bundles\/npmassets",
            "bower-asset-library": "web\/bundles\/bowerassets"
        }
    }
}
```

Is this expected behavior?

Comment: No, that's not expected behavior. I'd guess future attempts to run Composer will fail because of the `%`, too. I'd be inclined to blame one of the `post-install-cmd` or `post-update-cmd` scripts.

Comment: @ceejayoz - This was my initial impression too, but subsequent composer calls run fine, and I see there have been new releases of composer lately that add json encoding classes.   Just did not have time to go through their past changes to figure if this is the new behavior. Now, post-install and post-update  I had not thought of this, I will follow this lead, thanks!

Comment: That's very odd. The `%` really should break the `json_decode` calls Composer is presumably using internally.

Comment: @ceejayoz - The % was through git-diff,  is not there when I opened composer.json in vi,  I updated the question.  I re-ran composer and confirmed there is no %. but the slashes are always escaped, this is on 3 different environnements  with latest composer installed.

Comment: OK, that makes more sense. Sounds like they just switched up the options for `json_encode` a little, then - http://php.net/json_encode has a `JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES` flag. Both are valid. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1580647/json-why-are-forward-slashes-escaped.