# Cannot write correctly a link inside an .json file

Tags: java, websphere

I have a Dynamic Web Project + Maven deployed on WebSphere 8.5 with java 1.6 and I'm using the following library in the pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>com.googlecode.json-simple</groupId>
        <artifactId>json-simple</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.1</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
```

I get the environment's url and I'm trying to write it on a .json file.
Here is the code:

```
InetAddress ip;
    try {
        ip = InetAddress.getLocalHost();
        ip.getHostAddress();

        JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
        obj.put("name", "https:" + File.separatorChar + File.separatorChar + ip.getHostAddress() + ":443"
                + File.separatorChar + "authorizer" + File.separatorChar);
        obj.put("debugging", "true");

        FileWriter file = new FileWriter(ctx.getServletContext().getRealPath("/") + "/assets/conf.json");
        file.write(obj.toJSONString());
        file.flush();
        file.close();
    } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Well it works, but I get this on conf.json:

```
{"name":"https:\/\/126.0.0.0:443\/authorizer\/","debugging":"true"}
```

As you see, it is not formatted but when I have tested it on Windows just worked fine.
The thing is when I deployed on WebSphere I got the url wrong and the problem It's on the way of the forward slash. How can I write the url correctly?

I have tried already with `File.separator`, or simply writing `"/"` or `"\\"` but neither worked.

Comment: Since you are trying to construct a URL, and not a path to a file in the file system, you should not be using `File.separator`, you should simply use "/". On Windows OSs File.separator is a \, on unix-based OSs, it is /. On Windows particularly, you don't want the URLS to _ever_ have \.

Comment: I got this
{"name":"https:\/126.0.0.0:443\/authorizer\/","debugging":"true"}

Answer (score 0):

Don't use File.separator to construct URLs, simply use `/`. The path-separator for URLs is the same regardless of the OS. File.separator is different depending on the OS (Windows is `\`, most other OSs are `/`). I rewrote a portion of your code to demo the construction of the URL. Notice when you get the URL from the Json object, it is formatted properly (see the line: `System.out.println("the URL recovered from Json:...`). The output from that line looks like:

`the URL recovered from Json: https://127.0.1.1:443/authorizer/`

```
public static void main(String... args) throws  Exception {

    InetAddress ip;
    ip = InetAddress.getLocalHost();
    ip.getHostAddress();

    String url0 = "https:" + File.separatorChar + File.separatorChar + ip.getHostAddress() + ":443"
            + File.separatorChar + "authorizer" + File.separatorChar;
    String url1 = "https:" + "//" + ip.getHostAddress() + ":443"
            + "/" + "authorizer" + "/";
    JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
    obj.put("name", url0);
    obj.put("debugging", "true");

    System.out.println("the URL recovered from Json: " + obj.get("name"));

    System.out.println("json: " + obj.toJSONString());
    System.out.println("this url will be different than what you want on Windows:\n" + url0);
    System.out.println("this is what you want, it will be the same on all OSs:\n" + url1);
}
```

It appears that Json allows `/` to be escaped, but does not require it. So escaping the `/` is not incorrect, just unnecessary in your case. See: [JSON: why are forward slashes escaped?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1580647/json-why-are-forward-slashes-escaped)