# laravel database notification store url added \\ to //

Tags: php, mysql, database, laravel, notifications

does anyone know why database notification url added \ on //?

## scenery

I have a notification table I want to store a url as data array inside notification class , but the url get added \ , below is my code, when I using the eloquent url is not getting strip meaning store whatever I pass in database.

```
public function toDatabase()
{
    return [
        // 'msg' => "Your Comment On ". $this->post->getAttributes()['title'] ." Was Approved Please click <a href='".route('$this->post->slug')."'>here</a> to view it",

        'msg' => "https://google.com" ,
    ];
}
```

what is actually store inside my db when I invoke the notify class

```
{"msg":"https:\/\/google.com"}
```

look like they have added mysql prevention, but query builder is injection-free as stated on the doc correct me if I am wrong
thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What actually stored in your notification table is a json format as you can seen it's `key:value` pair json

```
{"msg":"https:\/\/google.com"}
```

to get the data of your notificaiton you need to `json_decode()` the data like so

```
json_decode($notification->data);
```

you can also, refer to this question "[why-are-forward-slashes-escaped](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1580647/json-why-are-forward-slashes-escaped)" to know more about escaping forward slash

Answer (score 0):

another turn around I come up is the encode the url then store inside db