# What's the equivalent of java jsonObject.escape in javascript

Tags: javascript, json

I can't find the equivalent of the escape method that exists for java here https://www.tutorialspoint.com/json_simple/json_simple_escape_characters.htm

```
text = jsonObject.escape(text);
```

in javascript ?

Comment: `JSON.stringify()`?

Comment: That is a strange method. The documentation says *"The following characters are reserved characters and can not be used in JSON...`JSONObject.escape()` method can be used to escape such reserved keywords in a JSON String."*. If you have a JSON string, then how could you ever have reserved characters in it, as that would make it NOT a JSON string in the first place...

Answer (score 0):

The documentation you refer to, gives this Java example:

> ### Example
>
> ```java
> import org.json.simple.JSONObject;
>
> public class JsonDemo {
>    public static void main(String[] args) {
>       JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
>       String text = "Text with special character /\"\'\b\f\t\r\n.";
>       System.out.println(text);
>       System.out.println("After escaping.");
>       text = jsonObject.escape(text);
>       System.out.println(text); 
>    } 
> }
> ```
>
> ### Output
>
> ```
> Text with special character /"'
> . 
> After escaping. 
> Text with special character \/\"'\b\f\t\r\n.
> ```

The same can be achieved in JavaScript as follows:

```js
let text = "Text with special character /\"\'\b\f\t\r\n.";
console.log(text);
console.log("After escaping.");
text = JSON.stringify(text).slice(1, -1); // Encode and remove the wrapping double quotes.
console.log(text);
```

There is one difference in the output: the `JSON.simple` Java library escapes the forward slash, JavaScript's `JSON.stringify` doesn't.

JSON does [not require the slash to be escaped](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1580647/5459839). Note also that the above mentioned documentation does not list it as a "reserved character", so `JSONObject.escape()` escapes a bit more than is essential (but it doesn't hurt).