# Problem parsing through Ajax a JSON data fetched by PHP file

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, ajax

I have difficulty parsing JSON date from my PHP file

```
{"date":"20\/12\/2022","result":"£13000.00","medias":"BBC","country":"UK"}
```

but when I try to parse it and to see the data in the console.log - it's empty

Please help

My Ajax Function

```js
function ajax_call(){
    const style2 = $("#style1").val();
    const radio_btn = $('input[name="drone"]:checked').val();
    if(style2==""){
        document.getElementById("error").innerHTML = "Error: Please enter style code !"; 
        return false;
    } 
    {
        $.ajax({ 
            type: 'post',
            url: "t.php",  
            data: { styles: style2 , country: radio_btn},
            dataType: "json",
            success: function(data){  
                var jsondata = $.parseJSON(data);
                console.log(jsondata);
            }
        })
    }
}
```

My PHP

```php
<php

header('Content-type: application/json');
$date = "20/12/2020";
$end_result = "£13000.00";
$medias = "BBC";
$country = "UK";

$sortjson = array('date' => $date,  
                    'result' =>iconv('Windows-1252', 'UTF-8', $end_result), 
                    'medias' => $medias, 
                    'country' => $country
            );

echo json_encode($sortjson, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
?>
```

Comment: Most likely you are not waiting for an answer to the promise.

Comment: What is the output of the console.log(data) you may see it as a string

Comment: Also try adding this to Ajax call         

dataType: "text" or dataType: "json"

Comment: I dont have any output in the console.log i have the response in devtool for the ajax call which return the thing i want .

Comment: same i don't get any console.log respone

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? If dumping `data` yields nothing, did you check that the request is sent properly?

Comment: Good code indentation would help us read the code and more importantly it will help **you debug your code**
[Take a quick look at a coding standard](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-12/) for your own benefit. You may be asked to amend this code
in a few weeks/months and you will thank me in the end.

Comment: May be worth a read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1580647/json-why-are-forward-slashes-escaped

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe there is a typo in the PHP code, you need to change the first line from:

```
<php
```

to

```
<?php
```

If the first line is `<php`, the output won't be valid JSON.

Complete PHP code:

```
<?php

header('Content-type: application/json');
$date = "20/12/2020";
$end_result = "£13000.00";
$medias = "BBC";
$country = "UK";

$sortjson = array('date' => $date,  'result' =>iconv('Windows-1252', 'UTF-8', $end_result), 'medias' => $medias, 'country' => $country);


echo json_encode($sortjson, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);

?>
```

Also, I'm not 100% sure you need the iconv call, you could try the below code:

```
<?php

header('Content-type: application/json');
$date = "20/12/2020";
$end_result = "£13000.00";
$medias = "BBC";
$country = "UK";

$sortjson = array('date' => $date,  'result' => $end_result, 'medias' => $medias, 'country' => $country);

echo json_encode($sortjson, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);

?>
```

Answer (score -1):

You have a error in your **Success** method:

use **JSON.parse()** method instead of **$.parseJSON()**

```
success: function(data){  

   var jsondata = JSON.parse(data);
   console.log(jsondata);
}
```

Comment: Same , empty console.log

Comment: $.parseJSON(data) === JSON.parse(data);

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it. What did you change, and why?

Answer (score -1):

You have to use JSON.parse()

```
function ajax_call(){
const style2 = $("#style1").val();
const radio_btn = $('input[name="drone"]:checked').val();
if(style2==""){document.getElementById("error").innerHTML = "Error: Please enter style code !"; return false;} {
$.ajax({ 
    type: 'post',
    url: "t.php",  
    data: { styles: style2 , country: radio_btn},
                  dataType: "json",
                 success: function(data){  
   var jsondata = JSON.parse(data);
        console.log(jsondata);
}
})
}
}
```

Comment: same thing empty console.log

Comment: $.parseJSON(data) === JSON.parse(data);

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it. What did you change, and why?