# Incorrect Conversion to JSON

Tags: r, jsonlite

I have html as character in R and trying to convert it to JSON using `jsonlite` package.

```
   toJSON("<span>ASD</span>")
```

It returns `<\/span>` instead of `</span>`

```
["<span>ASD<\/span>"]
```

`cat(toJSON("<span>ASD</span>"))` also returns the same conversion

Comment: cat(toJSON("<span>ASD</span>")) is giving the same escaped version in the console.

Comment: Which package are you using for the `toJSON` function?

Comment: jsonlite package

Comment: Ok. It seems that escaping the forward slash is optional in JSON https://stackoverflow.com/q/1580647/2372064 and that jsonlite has decided do escape it by default. This doesn't appear to be a setting you can change. But since it's allowed by the spec normal JSON readers shouldn't have a problem correctly reading in the data as a single slash. Related github issue: https://github.com/jeroen/jsonlite/issues/255

Comment: Note that `rjson::toJSON("<span>ASD</span>")` does not escape the slash. So different R packages have different behaviors.

Comment: `jsonify::to_json("<span>ASD</span>")` doesn't escape the `/` either.