# mapOf("regNumber" to "CES/2020/19423") converted to RequestBody? when read becomes {"regNumber":"CES\/2020\/19423"}

Tags: json, kotlin, okhttp

Please how do I convert to OkHttp RequestBody in a way that extra backslash[\] won't get added to my string value?

**My Implementation**

```
val requestBody = mapOf("regNumber" to "CES/2020/19423").toRequestBody() // my extension func.
val buffer = Buffer()
requestBody.writeTo(buffer)
Log.d("BodyString", buffer.readUtf8())
```

**Response**
`BodyString: {"regNumber":"CES\/2020\/19423"}`

**What I Want**
`BodyString: {"regNumber":"CES/2020/19423"}`

Comment: Why do you need / want to do that? Escaping forward slashes in JSON is somewhat common, see https://stackoverflow.com/q/1580647/610979

Comment: Thanks @FrankSchmitt.
The issue is within my toRequestBody() ext function. I just discovered that it's really a JSON issue.

Answer (score 0):

Within my toRequestBody extension function, I previously converted my map to a JsonObject. I realized that it was the JsonObject that was including the extra  backslach "\"

**My final solution that resolved it**

```
internal inline fun <reified T> T.toRequestBody(): RequestBody {
    val jsonBodyStr = Gson().toJson(this, T::class.java)
    return jsonBodyStr.toRequestBody("application/json;charset=utf8".toMediaTypeOrNull())
}
```