# Is there is a more concise representation of Infinity in JSON than 1e309?

Tags: json, floating-point, nan, infinity

It's the smallest I could find.

Comment: Please also refer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1423081/json-left-out-infinity-and-nan-json-status-in-ecmascript.

Comment: the unicode symbol "∞"?  http://unicodinator.com/#221E ok, I know you want a Number.

Answer (score -1):

The JSON RFC ( https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4627 ) states that NaN, Positive Infinity and Negative Infinity cannot be represented in JSON:

> Numeric values that cannot be represented as sequences of digits (such as Infinity and NaN) are not permitted.

I don't know where you're getting 1*10^309 from, because Javascript's maximum exact integer value is 2^53.

When you say "concise" do you actually mean "succinct"?

Comment: "Javascript's maximum numeric value is 2^53" - I don't think that's correct.  IIUC, Javascript uses IEEE 754 binary64 format to store all numbers (whether integer or float).  2^53 is significant in that all integer values not exceeding 2^53 in absolute value can be represented exactly, but a JS Number can represent values up to 2^1024 - 2^971, which is around 1.8e308.

Comment: Yes, you're right. 2^53 is the maximum value for integer values (based on the number of significant bits available). I forgot about floating value limits (despite this actually being a thread about floats).

Comment: it does not say anything about using null as infinity

Comment: @DataGreed Thank you for the correction, I have revised my answer.