# What is the shortest decimal floating-point value that will overflow a 64-bit double to Infinity?

Tags: floating-point, ieee-754

Other that Infinity itself, of course.

The shortest I've found is `1e309`.

(This is essentially a rehash of: [Is there is a more concise representation of Infinity in JSON than 1e309?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12334559/is-there-is-a-more-concise-representation-of-infinity-in-json-than-1e309))

Comment: Not shorter, but smaller: 2e308

Comment: Hmm. Along those lines, the smallest might begin with 9

Comment: Do you think that beginning with a `9` is going to be sufficient to save a digit on the exponent?