# JSON.stringify converting Infinity to null

Tags: javascript, json, infinity, stringify

I have JavaScript Object say:

```
var a = {b: Infinity, c: 10};
```

When I do

```
var b = JSON.stringify(a);
```

it returns the following

b = "{"b":null, "c":10}";

How is the JSON.stringify converts the object to strings?

I tried [MDN Solution](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Using_native_JSON).

```
function censor(key, value) {
  if (value == Infinity) {
    return "Infinity";
  }
  return value;
}
var b = JSON.stringify(a, censor);
```

But in this case I have to return the string "Infinity" not `Infinity`. If I return Infinity it again converts Infinity to null.

How do I solve this problem.

Comment: Maybe for some use cases it's just fine to use another low or high number: `Number.MIN_SAFE_INTEGER` or `Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER`

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Like the other answers stated, `Infinity` is not part of the values JSON can store as value.

You can reverse the censor method on parsing the JSON:

```
var c = JSON.parse(b, function (key, value) {
    return value === "Infinity" ? Infinity : value;
});
```

Comment: This I can always do, but it would be nice to get the Infinity not "Infinity", as I don't need to perform this additional check on my hundreds of objects having hundreds of properties.

Comment: As I wrote in my answer, a JSON file containing `Infinity` (without quotes) as a value won't be valid JSON. You shouldn't want to write non-standard-compliant JSON files.

Comment: @DigvijayYadav, I fear you'll have to live with the nature of the beast.

Comment: Also see [`reviver` parameter in docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse#the_reviver_parameter)

Answer (score 8):

JSON doesn't have Infinity or NaN, see this question:

[JSON left out Infinity and NaN; JSON status in ECMAScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1423081/json-left-out-infinity-and-nan-json-status-in-ecmascript)

Hence `{ b: Infinity, c: 10 }` isn't valid JSON. If you need to encode infinity in JSON, you probably have to resort to objects:

```
{
    "b": { "is_infinity": true, "value": null },
    "c": { "is_infinity": false, "value": 10 }
}
```

This structure is generated by, given your above example does what you say it does,

```
function censor(key, value) {
  if (value == Infinity) {
    return JSON.stringify ( { is_infinity: true, value: null } );
  } else {
    return JSON.stringify ( { is_infinity: false, value: value } );
  }
}
var b = JSON.stringify(a, censor);
```

Answer (score 5):

JSON doesn't support infinity/Nan.

Please refer the below links.

http://www.markhansen.co.nz/inspecting-with-json-stringify/

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify

[JSON left out Infinity and NaN; JSON status in ECMAScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1423081/json-left-out-infinity-and-nan-json-status-in-ecmascript)

Thanks,

Siva

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this lack of support when sending an object from an expressJS server using `res.json()`. When `Infinity` value was present the client-side was receiving the value `null` in its place.

I'm just posting what I did for my particular scenario, as it may be useful to someone coming here for a similar scenario.

In my particular instance the possible options for this specific value where either a number or `Infinity`.

So I ended up converting that value to a string with `toString()` (so a number, for example, `250` would become a string `'250'` and `Infinity` would become `'Infinity'`).

Then on the client-side I would convert the value to a number using `Number()`. That would revert `Infinity` to the number type `Infinity`.

So here is what it looks like:

The Object

```
myObj = {
  numberValue: Infinity, // or some other number
  otherKey: 'otherValue'
}
```

On server

```
myObj.numberValue = myObj.numberValue.toString();
res.json(myObj);
```

On client

```
fetch('/some-path', options)
  .then(res => res.json())
  .then(data => {
    data.numberValue = Number(data.numberValue);
    // do stuff with the data
  })
```