# Force JSON.stringify() to emit NaN / Infinity or JS JSON lib that does so

Tags: javascript, json, nan, infinity

I'm looking into the feasibility of adding NaN/Infinity support to a pre-existing scientific application that uses JSONRPC for client/server interactions. Many JSON libs do handle (optionally in some cases) NaNs and Infs, for example:

- Python [json](http://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html#infinite-and-nan-number-values) reads and writes
- Java [Jackson](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson) reads but writes strings instead of barewords
- Java [GSON](http://google-gson.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/gson/docs/javadocs/com/google/gson/GsonBuilder.html#serializeSpecialFloatingPointValues%28%29) reads and writes
- Javascript can [read](https://github.com/Canop/JSON.parseMore)

I'm aware that NaN and Infinity are not supported in the [JSON spec](http://www.json.org/), and am aware of the [related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1423081/json-left-out-infinity-and-nan-json-status-in-ecmascript) [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16644597/json-stringify-converting-infinity-to-null/). However, AFAICT the question of whether there's some way of coercing the native JS `JSON.stringify()` method to emit NaN/Infinity or, alternately, there's a JS JSON library that does the same is unanswered. A subtle difference to the referenced questions, perhaps, but important. So far I've been unable to discover such a method or library, so here I am. Is the only option writing one's own JSON serializer?

Note that the `replacement` parameter of `JSON.stringify()` is not helpful, at least in my hands.

**UPDATE:** Emitting NaN/Infinity etc. as strings makes the semantics of those strings ambiguous. They need to be emitted as barewords as in the Python and GSON implementations.

Comment: This is exactly a `replacement` parameter job, it's not so difficult. Perhaps you can specify more about your actual problem, along with an example and sample data?

Comment: JSON.stringify({a:1,b:1/"gg", c:{d:5}}, function(a,b,c){if(Object.is(NaN, b)){return "NaN";} return b;})

Comment: @dandavis see the update above.

Comment: If you're going to downvote the question, at least explain what's wrong with it so I can fix it.

Comment: you can use a guid instead of, ex:"NaN" if you're worried about string collisions and want the use the fast native parser.

Comment: @dandavis yeah, but then you lose the human readability of json and anyone examining the Json will likely get confused.  Seems a bit too hacky to me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is an example

Javascript

```
var array1 = [-Infinity, -1, 0, 1, 2, NaN, 4, 5, Infinity],
    json = JSON.stringify(array1, function (key, value) {
        if (value !== value) {
            return 'NaN';
        }

        if (value === Infinity) {
            return 'Infinity';
        }

        if (value === -Infinity) {
            return '-Infinity';
        }

        return value;
    }),
    array2 = JSON.parse(json, function (key, value) {
        if (value === 'NaN') {
            return NaN;
        }

        if (value === 'Infinity') {
            return Infinity;
        }

        if (value === '-Infinity') {
            return -Infinity;
        }

        return value;
    });

console.log(json);
console.log(array2);
```

Output

```
["-Infinity",-1,0,1,2,"NaN",4,5,"Infinity"]
[-Infinity, -1, 0, 1, 2, NaN, 4, 5, Infinity]
```

References

[JSON.stringify](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify)

[JSON.parse](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse)

On [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Xotic750/zH2t4/)

**Update:**

Javascript

```
var array1 = [-Infinity, -1, 0, 1, 2, NaN, 4, 5, Infinity],
    json = JSON.stringify(array1, function (key, value) {
        if (value !== value) {
            return '0/0';
        }

        if (value === 1/0) {
            return '1/0';
        }

        if (value === -1/0) {
            return '-1/0';
        }

        return value;
    }),
    array2 = JSON.parse(json, function (key, value) {
        if (value === '0/0') {
            return 0/0;
        }

        if (value === '1/0') {
            return Infinity;
        }

        if (value === '-1/0') {
            return -1/0;
        }

        return value;
    });

console.log(json);
console.log(array2);
```

Output

```
["-1/0",-1,0,1,2,"0/0",4,5,"1/0"]
[-Infinity, -1, 0, 1, 2, NaN, 4, 5, Infinity]
```

On [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Xotic750/n3Qua/)

Comment: See update above - the semantics of the strings you use are now ambigious.

Comment: How are they [ambiguous](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ambiguity)? You haven't provided us with any example a data. The example that I used is numbers only. Therefore these string representations in this context  are not ambiguous, they only represent those specific values.

Comment: If you want a library that does not comply to specification, I would suggest that you get a copy of ['JSON2'](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js) and modify the code to suit your needs.

Comment: Or if it is the string representations that you are worried about and want an alternative then try `If you evaluate 1/0 you get Infinity, if you evaluate -1/0 you get -Infinity, if you evaluate 0/0 you get NaN.`

Comment: Because, for example, the string Infinity now has two possible meanings - the string Infinity and the numeric representation of infinity, and there's no way for the receiver to know which meaning to choose. There's no way for me to provide sample data that represents all the cases that could occur - it could be virtually any object.

Comment: yeah, hacking code is what I'm hoping to avoid, but it's a last resort. I'd obviously rather use pre-existing, well used & tested libraries.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand your 3rd comment. How would you implement this?

Comment: If you do not have control over the receiver then how are you going to get them to use a non standard spec JSON, if not by through agreement? Otherwise you can just as easily agree what strings will represent said values.

Comment: I do have control over the receiver - I don't have control over the contents of the JSON. That means that semantic additions to JSON (e.g. the barewords NaN, Infinity etc [which are how most of the libs that do handle NaN, Infinity have implemented it]) are ok, because they won't alter data. Changing the meanings of arbitrary strings can alter data.

Comment: Then you have no choice but to modify one of the existing libraries, `JSON`, `JSON2` or `JSON3` to handle those raw, and then push your custom library out to your clients or whatever. It isn't so hard to do.

Comment: Very minor changes to `JSON2` and now you have a non standard `JSON` library that gives you barewords: http://jsfiddle.net/Xotic750/mswgn/ Outputs `[-Infinity,-1,0,1,2,NaN,4,5,Infinity]` and `[-Infinity, -1, 0, 1, 2, NaN, 4, 5, Infinity]`

Comment: Heh, I must've been looking at the code at the same time you were, and yeah, the hack is trivial. JSON3 looks just as simple to hack.

Answer (score 0):

`replacement` parameter of `JSON.stringify` is quite right tool for the job.

```
JSON.stringify(data, function(key, value) {
   if (value === Infinity) {
      return "Infinity";
   } else if (value === -Infinity) {
      return "-Infinity";
   } else if (value !== value) {
      return "NaN";
   }
   return value;
});
```

And on the other side you can use `reviver` parameter of `JSON.parse`.

```
 JSON.parse(data, function(key, value) {
   if (value === "Infinity") {
      return Infinity;
   } else if (value === "-Infinity") {
      return -Infinity;
   } else if (value === "NaN") {
      return NaN;
   }
   return value;
});
```

Comment: No need for the `else`s after `return`s

Comment: See the update above - the solution here introduces ambiguity into the semantics of the strings you chose to represent NaN & Inf.

Comment: @Xotic750 I prefer the `else if`, as it makes code shorter and doesn't affect functionality in this case. But thanks for noticing.

Comment: @elhefe I agree, they are now ambigous, nothing more we can do using existing native implementation. I see, you found solution, hacking on JSON2 library. GL