# Angular >= 2: What's the way to read nan/undefined/infinity from JSON?

Tags: json, angular

My backend web service sometimes needs to return `NaN` or `infinite` values. However, there is no standard JSON representation of such values.

On the front end, we are using angular. Does its http client have some support/convention for reading such values from a json response?

Comment: For NaN you could use `null`, and infinite could be `Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER`. Either that or make it an object with some properties that fill your need.

Comment: You could replace NaN/infinite with `null`/`undefined`/`Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER` with an Http Interceptor.(https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpInterceptor)

Comment: @YassineZeriouh: thanks, interesting

Comment: you can not intercept the http responses for this, because its a value criteria, not a response criteria

Comment: I think [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21897413/3681565) is more what you are looking for