# What is the exact difference between the ternary operator and && operator?

Tags: javascript

I was just playing a code, and I found a little mysterious behavior with my code while turning the ternary operator into `&&` and `||` operator:

```js
let  a = 3;
a = a > 1 && 2 || a;
console.log(a);

let b = 3;
b = b > 1 ? 2 : b;
console.log(b);

// a and b both are same. It's fine.

const getAdjacentHighestProduct = (arr) => {
  let max = -Infinity;
  arr.reduce((a, c) => {
    let product = a * c;
    max = product > max ? product : max;
    return a = c;
  });
  return max;
};

const aProduct = getAdjacentHighestProduct([1, 0, 1, 0, 1000]);
console.log(aProduct);

const getAdjacentHighestProduct2 = (arr) => {
  let max = -Infinity;
  arr.reduce((a, c) => {
    let product = a * c;
    max = product > max && product || max;
    return a = c;
  });
  return max;
};

const aProduct2 = getAdjacentHighestProduct2([1, 0, 1, 0, 1000]);
console.log(aProduct2);

// aProduct, aProduct2 are not the same. It's not okay.
```

Also, here I can see the result is `-Infinity` for aProduct2. But while trying the same code in a test case, I am seeing the result is `null`, maybe it's due environment (browser vs node.js).

So, I am curious why both results are not the same and why is it returning `-Infinity` or `null` rather than `0`?

So, what's exact difference between using a ternary operator and `&& ||` operator?

Here's the screenshot of the test result:

[image]

Comment: They're completely different?

Comment: @Pointy But what's the *exact* difference?

Comment: Have you checked one of countless JavaScript references on the Internet? You can read the complete spec if you like.

Comment: I'm getting 0 for aProduct and -Infinity for aProduct2. And in the test case I am getting `null` so why is it resulting different behavior?

Comment: @Point I think \@GeorgeJempty was being sarcastic

Comment: Why not just `max = Math.max(product, max)` ? or `if(product > max) max = product` ?

Comment: @ııı yes sorry I started typing that before that comment :)

Comment: @JonasWilms I wanted to know the difference, so was playing code.

Comment: Maybe you can create a more basic example? I think you're being downvoted because your question seems a little odd since at first glance they seem to be apples and oranges. Or maybe this is more of an XY problem. What are you actually trying to accomplish and what's not working?

Comment: @j08691 I wanted to know why aProduct2 is resulting `-Infinity` or `null` rather than 0?

Comment: I don't see any `null`, neither in browser nor in node :/

Comment: @JonasWilms: go for it! ;)

Comment: I mean really. This question shows some medium complicated code and the question is then "I do change some operators and my code is returning different results?".

Comment: @sjahan thanks for confirming that. But, it would be nice to know what they use for test cases.

Comment: @Pointy I would love to read the reference, can you please share the link if you know. Thanks. ( I didn't find anything interesting that would result `null` in my example case)

Comment: @BhojendraRauniyar well what exactly did your "test case" look like? The posted code cannot return `null`.

Comment: @Pointy for the same I am receiving the `null` in the test case. I'll post a screenshot in my post.

Comment: For what it's worth, `return a = c` has exactly the same effect as `return c`

Comment: Thanks @Pointy. Also, can you please share me the link you're trying to say me to follow on? I din't find anything like that. (I'm trying to develop my js skill better)

Comment: There's [the general "Expressions" stuff at MDN for starters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Expressions_and_Operators).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks everyone! I got the answer. Let's break them here:

(I hope, you understand, don't  think to give explanation)

```
0 > -Infinity && 0 || -Infinity
false > -Infinity && false || -Infinity
false > -Infinity
```

The `null` value was my key point of curiosity. Ah, I just found the [right answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16644597/json-stringify-converting-infinity-to-null):

```js
var a = {b: Infinity, c: 10};
console.log(JSON.stringify(a));
```

So, I think they use JSON.stringify to satisfy the test result.

Comment: Your question made no mention of `JSON` though

Comment: @ııı yeah, I'm not sure what they use in their test cases. I just inserted a screenshot in my post.

Comment: Ah, thats why I couldn't find the `null` ... :)

Answer (score 4):

In case `b` is falsy, `true ? b : c` will be `b` whereas `true && b || c` will be `c`.

```js
function ternary(a, b, c) {
  return a ? b : c;
}
function andOr(a, b, c) {
  return a && b || c;
}

console.log(ternary(1, 0, 3), andOr(1, 0, 3));
```

Comment: *hang on are you also being sarcastic?*

Comment: @JonasWilms If not sarcastic, then are you sure it's `null` and not `NaN`?

Comment: It's `null`, that's what amazed me to post the question.

Comment: I can't see how it can be `null`. Can you post an example that reproduces that? Because you omit the initial value in `reduce()`, it will be `let product = undefined * 1`, which is `NaN`, but not null

Comment: @ııı if the second argument to `reduce` is omitted, the first iteration will be for the *second* value in the array, and the reduce "accumulator" will start off as the first value in the array. Thus the first iteration would have `a` as 1 and `b` as 0.

Comment: @Pointy Oh, true.

Answer (score -2):

The difference is: they do different things. ;)

## Ternary Operator

```
x = c ? a : b

if c then
  x = a;
else
  x = b;
end if
```

## Logical AND

```
x = a && b
```

## Logical OR

```
x = a || b
```

Comment: I know that, but in my particular example why results are different?

Comment: Because you changed the operators?

Comment: What do you even intend to do with this line?? You know that you're mixing boolean and integer values?

a = a > 1 && 2 || a;

Comment: JavaScript has short-circuiting. Please look that up before trying to be clever. Also there are no integers in js.

Comment: @JonasWilms I will be waiting for your answer, really.

Comment: not trying to be clever. I try to be dumb to clarify your question. Is your question about short circuiting? Why not make an easy example?