# How do you JSON.stringify an ES6 Map?

Tags: javascript, json, dictionary, ecmascript-6

I'd like to start using [ES6 Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) instead of JS objects but I'm being held back because I can't figure out how to `JSON.stringify()` a `Map`.  My keys are guaranteed to be strings and my values will always be listed.  Do I really have to write a wrapper method to serialize?

Comment: interesting article on the topic http://2ality.com/2015/08/es6-map-json.html

Comment: I was able to get this to work.  The results are on Plunkr at http://embed.plnkr.co/oNlQQBDyJUiIQlgWUPVP/.  The solution uses a JSON.stringify(obj, replacerFunction) which checks to see if a Map object is being passed and converts the Map object to a Javascript object (that JSON.stringify) will then convert to a string.

Comment: If your keys are guaranteed to be strings (or numbers) and your values *arrays*, you can do something like `[...someMap.entries()].join(';')`; for something more complex you could try something similar using something like `[...someMap.entries()].reduce((acc, cur) => acc + \`${cur[0]}:${/* do something to stringify cur[1] */ }\`, '')`

Comment: @Oriol What if it is possible for key name to be same as default properties? `obj[key]` may get you something unexpected. Consider the case `if (!obj[key]) obj[key] = newList; else obj[key].mergeWith(newList);`.

Comment: Even MDN suggesting this Stack Overflow link

Answer (score 434, accepted):

Both `JSON.stringify` and `JSON.parse` support a second argument. `replacer` and `reviver` respectively. With replacer and reviver below it's possible to add support for native Map object, including deeply nested values

```js
function replacer(key, value) {
  if(value instanceof Map) {
    return {
      dataType: 'Map',
      value: Array.from(value.entries()), // or with spread: value: [...value]
    };
  } else {
    return value;
  }
}
```

```js
function reviver(key, value) {
  if(typeof value === 'object' && value !== null) {
    if (value.dataType === 'Map') {
      return new Map(value.value);
    }
  }
  return value;
}
```

**Usage**:

```js
const originalValue = new Map([['a', 1]]);
const str = JSON.stringify(originalValue, replacer);
const newValue = JSON.parse(str, reviver);
console.log(originalValue, newValue);
```

Deep nesting with combination of Arrays, Objects and Maps

```js
const originalValue = [
  new Map([['a', {
    b: {
      c: new Map([['d', 'text']])
    }
  }]])
];
const str = JSON.stringify(originalValue, replacer);
const newValue = JSON.parse(str, reviver);
console.log(originalValue, newValue);
```

Comment: Just marked this as correct. While I don't like the fact you have to "dirty up" the data across the wire with a non-standardized `dataType`, I can't think of a cleaner way.  Thanks.

Comment: @rynop yeah it's more like a little program with it's own data storage format than just using pure native functionality

Comment: @Pawel what is the reason for using `this[key]` instead of `value`?

Comment: @JimiDini good point, updated. Now if someone wants to declare these as arrow functions it won't mess with the scope

Comment: To me there seems to be a slight problem: any ordinary object o which by chance has the property o.dataType==='Map' will also be converted to a Map when you serialize-deserialize it.

Comment: @mkoe sure, but the probability of that is somewhere between being hit by a lightning and being hit by a lightning while hiding in a basement

Comment: If anyone is tempted to use `Object.fromEntries()` as stated in the [MDN Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/fromEntries)  I highly advise against it. You can parse a `Map` to an `Object` but not back! It will throw a `object is not iterable` error.

Comment: @mkoe I wrote an answer which actually fixes that problem.

Comment: There is a misplaced comma in the replacer function: "value: Array.from(value.entries()),"

Comment: @F.K.Juliano this is a "dangling comma" which is there at purpose for git diffs

Comment: You actually don't need to map.entries in the replacer, you can just array.from(map).

Comment: @Stefnotch this could be exploited this way, but what's preventing anyone from changing any other data types in a payload i.e. [] to {} ? To prevent this validation is required and when a payload is validated it's happening after parsing so it becomes pretty clear that the field is not of object but map type

Comment: It still does remain a footgun as is IMO. And there's apparently another sneaky case where it breaks. If one has some combination of the normal JSON `parse`, `stringify` and the `customParse` and `customStringify` from this answer, then one has to be really careful about how to apply them. Breakage could happen in a complex enough app with a backend and frontend.
That is, `customParse(customStringify( data ))` works. So does `customParse(stringify(parse(customStringify( data ))))`. But `customParse(stringify(customParse(customStringify(parse(customStringify( data )))))))` will break.

Comment: Which raises the question "how would that happen". Here's one scenario:
1. customStringify( data ) and send it over the network
2. naive network handler automatically JSON decodes it
<at this point you're not allowed to call customStringify followed by customParse on the object>
3. then we forward it, so we naively JSON encode it
4. customParse( data )

Comment: It is entirely possible that I just worry too much about correctness though. Either way, I would prefer it if people copied bulletproof code that they can rely on. As such, I am absolutely allowing and encouraging you to tweak your answer to actually handle that case, or to just copy the code from my answer. :)

Comment: @Stefnotch I agree that there could be a place that lets this slip through. i.e. a internal company npm package which is a wrapper for the api to pass some default options for auth headers and automatically parse JSON for convenience i.e. `const getUrl = (url) => fetch(url, apiOptions).then(res => res.json())` where `apiOptions` have some global settings. It's worth remembering that such cases may happen and these must be adapted correctly

Comment: @Pawel In that case, may I edit your lovely answer to include a more bulletproof way of handling such cases?

Comment: @Stefnotch that sounds like an architectural choice for a whole app so I don't see how a code change in this elementary transformation could handle this. Feel free to propse the change, although I find this answer simple and complete enough and reserve the right to undo the change if it makes the solution too complicated or the answer too verbose

Comment: @Pawel I submitted my edit, it makes the code slightly more complex, but should handle everything in a pretty bulletproof way. Let me know what you think.
(And then we can clean up those comments here.)

Comment: @Stefnotch thanks for trying, but it does make the answer much harder to understand. The best will be if you post the modified version as a new answer

Comment: @Pawel That's what I did down there :)

Comment: This will convert map values of `undefined` to `null` because `JSON.stringify` does said conversion when `undefined` is found in an array. Stringifying a plain object omits the undefined value instead of converting. This also means that stringify and parse will result in non-equivalent maps.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify#description

Answer (score 168):

You can't directly stringify the `Map` instance as it doesn't have any properties, but you can convert it to an array of tuples:

```
jsonText = JSON.stringify(Array.from(map.entries()));
```

For the reverse, use

```
map = new Map(JSON.parse(jsonText));
```

Comment: This does not convert to a JSON object, but instead to an Array of arrays. Not the same thing. See Evan Carroll's answer below for a more complete answer.

Comment: @SatThiru An array of tuples is the customary representation of `Map`s, it goes well with the constructor and iterator. Also it is the only sensible representation of maps that have non-string keys, and object would not work there.

Comment: Bergi, please note that OP said "My keys are guaranteed to be strings".

Comment: @SatThiru In that case, use [`JSON.stringify(Object.fromEntries(map.entries()))`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/fromEntries) and [`new Map(Object.entries(JSON.parse(jsonText)))`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries)

Comment: @Drenai Then don't use `Obect.fromEntries`, and use the code from my main answer instead of the one from the comment. The code that builds an object literal was in response to Sat Thiru, who gave the case that the keys are strings.

Answer (score 73):

You can't.

The keys of a map can be anything, including objects. But JSON syntax only allows strings as keys. So it's impossible in a general case.

> My keys are guaranteed to be strings and my values will always be lists

In this case, you can use a plain object. It will have these advantages:

- It will be able to be stringified to JSON.
- It will work on older browsers.
- It might be faster.

Comment: for the curious-in the latest chrome, any map serializes into '{}'

Comment: I have explained [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35078054/1529630) what exactly I meant when I said "you can't".

Comment: "It might be faster" - Do you have any source on that? I'm imagining a simple hash-map must be faster than a full blown object, but I have no proof. :)

Comment: @Lilleman I remember reading that a certain version of Firefox had the improvement of detecting when all keys in a map are strings, then it could be optimized more (like objects). So I guess maps will be slower on browsers without this kind of optimization. But that's implementation-dependent, and I haven't done any test to measure performance.

Comment: @Oriol Cool. I'm imagining the key always just being a pointer to a more advanced object anyways, so it should, in my head, always be optimized. In theory. I'll research this a bit I think. :)

Comment: Map > Object in performance scope - https://jsperf.com/es6-map-vs-object-properties/94

Comment: @Xplouder That test uses expensive `hasOwnProperty`. Without that, Firefox iterates objects much faster than maps. Maps are still faster on Chrome, though. http://jsperf.com/es6-map-vs-object-properties/95

Comment: True, seems that Firefox 45v iterates objects away faster than Chrome +49v. However Maps still wins vs objects in Chrome.

Comment: I am a little late to the party, but I had a similar need, and I was able to do this:  
`JSON.stringify(Array.from(myMap.entries()))`

Comment: A `Map` uses buckets to organize its keys. So, it should be faster than a simple property, especially when you have 1000 of them.

Comment: Just passing by and figure out my problem thanks to this. I really wish to move to a farm and leave all this behind, sometimes.

Comment: While this answer definitely points out the tricky bits, it most certainly is not "impossible" as the accepted answer demonstrates.

Comment: @Stefnotch https://imgur.com/a/cba5XXO

Comment: "*You can't. The keys of a map can be anything*" that's only true in the most generic possible case when the programmer has no knowledge or expectation of the data being serialised. However, in the exceptionally vast majority or cases, it's entirely possible, moreover, *trivial* to implement a serialisation for maps. Since you *know* what the data is, it's not hard to create an extremely simple serialise/deserialise pair that will work. Where it might get hard is if an object key holds more than their key/values. E.g. it's a class instance or a function. But it'd be dubious to serialise that.

Answer (score 49):

While there is no method provided by ecmascript yet, this can still be done using `JSON.stringify` if you map the `Map` to a JavaScript primitive. Here is the sample `Map` we'll use.

```js
const map = new Map();
map.set('foo', 'bar');
map.set('baz', 'quz');
```

## Going to an JavaScript Object

You can convert to JavaScript Object literal with the following helper function.

```js
const mapToObj = m => {
  return Array.from(m).reduce((obj, [key, value]) => {
    obj[key] = value;
    return obj;
  }, {});
};
    
JSON.stringify(mapToObj(map)); // '{"foo":"bar","baz":"quz"}'
```

## Going to a JavaScript Array of Objects

The helper function for this one would be even more compact

```js
const mapToAoO = m => {
  return Array.from(m).map( ([k,v]) => {return {[k]:v}} );
};
    
JSON.stringify(mapToAoO(map)); // '[{"foo":"bar"},{"baz":"quz"}]'
```

## Going to Array of Arrays

This is even easier, you can just use

```js
JSON.stringify( Array.from(map) ); // '[["foo","bar"],["baz","quz"]]'
```

Comment: > Going to an JavaScript Object <

Shouldn't it have code to handle keys such as `__proto__`? Or you can damage the entire environment by trying to serialize such a map. Alok's response doesn't suffer from this, I believe.

Comment: As pointed out in Oriol's answer, this is incorrect. Map keys can be objects, which this answer doesn't handle.

Answer (score 35):

Using [spread sytax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) Map can be serialized in one line:

```
JSON.stringify([...new Map()]);
```

and deserialize it with:

```
let map = new Map(JSON.parse(map));
```

Comment: This'll work for a one-dimensional Map, but not for an n-dimensional map.

Answer (score 30):

Given your example is a simple use case in which keys are going to be simple types, I think this is the easiest way to JSON stringify a Map.

```
JSON.stringify(Object.fromEntries(map));
```

The way I think about the underlying data structure of a Map is as an array of key-value pairs (as arrays themselves). So, something like this:

```
const myMap = new Map([
     ["key1", "value1"],
     ["key2", "value2"],
     ["key3", "value3"]
]);
```

Because that underlying data structure is what we find in Object.entries, we can utilize the native JavaScript method of `Object.fromEntries()` on a Map as we would on an Array:

```
Object.fromEntries(myMap);

/*
{
     key1: "value1",
     key2: "value2",
     key3: "value3"
}
*/
```

And then all you're left with is using JSON.stringify() on the result of that.

Comment: This one is nice but does require you to target ES2019.

Comment: Careful, this is just good if you want to go one way.`Object.fromEntries()` as stated in the [MDN Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/fromEntries) you can parse a `Map` to an `Object` but not back! It will throw a `object is not iterable` error.

Comment: @Megajin `Object.fromEntries()` is non-destructive, so you will still have your original Map intact.

Comment: @AlokSomani yes, you are right. However if you want to parse a JSON (or the newly created Object) back, it won't work.

Comment: Just for additional information, this is totally ok for Typescript users which are able to make sure that the whole map structure (meaning nested objects as well) have string keys `Map<string, otherType>`

Answer (score 15):

## A Better Solution

```js
    // somewhere...
    class Klass extends Map {

        toJSON() {
            var object = { };
            for (let [key, value] of this) object[key] = value;
            return object;
        }

    }

    // somewhere else...
    import { Klass as Map } from '@core/utilities/ds/map';  // <--wherever "somewhere" is

    var map = new Map();
    map.set('a', 1);
    map.set('b', { datum: true });
    map.set('c', [ 1,2,3 ]);
    map.set( 'd', new Map([ ['e', true] ]) );

    var json = JSON.stringify(map, null, '\t');
    console.log('>', json);
```

#### Output

```js
    > {
        "a": 1,
        "b": {
            "datum": true
        },
        "c": [
            1,
            2,
            3
        ],
        "d": {
            "e": true
        }
    }
```

Hope that is less cringey than the answers above.

Comment: I'm not sure that many will be satisfied with extending the core map class just to serialize it to a json...

Comment: They don't have to be, but it's a more SOLID way of doing it. Specifically, this aligns with the LSP and OCP principles of SOLID. That is, the native Map is being extended, not modified, and one can still use Liskov Substitution (LSP) with a native Map. Granted, it's more OOP than a lot of novices or staunch Functional Programming people would prefer, but at least it's beset upon a tried & true baseline of fundamental software design principles. If you wanted to implement Interface Segregation Principle (ISP) of SOLID, you can have a small `IJSONAble` interface (using TypeScript, of course).

Comment: Yes, this is a good solution since it can produce specific serialisation variations. You can do `new MyMap1(someMap)` or `new MyMap2(someMap)` to clone and extend exiting maps easily. And then `MyMap1` and `MyMap2` can have different serialisation. For example, one might just serialise to a list of tuples, the other to an object. Furthermore, there can be special handling for serialising keys (since those could be arbitrary objects) or similar. The `replacer` option in `JSON.stringify` works OK but if it has to handle multiple types, it becomes cumbersome.

Answer (score 15):

### Correctly round-tripping serialization

Just copy this and use it. Or use [the npm package](https://github.com/stefnotch/json-safe-stringify).

```js
const serialize = (value) => JSON.stringify(value, stringifyReplacer);
const deserialize = (text) => JSON.parse(text, parseReviver);

// License: CC0
function stringifyReplacer(key, value) {
  if (typeof value === "object" && value !== null) {
    if (value instanceof Map) {
      return {
        _meta: { type: "map" },
        value: Array.from(value.entries()),
      };
    } else if (value instanceof Set) { // bonus feature!
      return {
        _meta: { type: "set" },
        value: Array.from(value.values()),
      };
    } else if ("_meta" in value) {
      // Escape "_meta" properties
      return {
        ...value,
        _meta: {
          type: "escaped-meta",
          value: value["_meta"],
        },
      };
    }
  }
  return value;
}

function parseReviver(key, value) {
  if (typeof value === "object" && value !== null) {
    if ("_meta" in value) {
      if (value._meta.type === "map") {
        return new Map(value.value);
      } else if (value._meta.type === "set") {
        return new Set(value.value);
      } else if (value._meta.type === "escaped-meta") {
        // Un-escape the "_meta" property
        return {
          ...value,
          _meta: value._meta.value,
        };
      } else {
        console.warn("Unexpected meta", value._meta);
      }
    }
  }
  return value;
}
```

### Why is this hard?

It should be possible to input any kind of data, get valid JSON, and from there *correctly* reconstruct the input.

This means dealing with

- Maps that have objects as keys `new Map([ [{cat:1}, "value"] ])`. This means that any answer which uses `Object.fromEntries` is probably wrong.
- Maps that have nested maps `new Map([ ["key", new Map([ ["nested key", "nested value"] ])] ])`. A lot of answers sidestep this by only answering the question and not dealing with anything beyond that.
- Mixing objects and maps `{"key": new Map([ ["nested key", "nested value"] ]) }`.

and on top of those difficulties, the serialisation format must be unambiguous. Otherwise one cannot always reconstruct the input. The top answer has one failing test case, see below.

Hence, I wrote this improved version. It uses `_meta` instead of `dataType`, to make conflicts rarer and if a conflict does happen, it actually unambiguously handles it. Hopefully the code is also simple enough to easily be extended to handle other containers.

My answer does, however, not attempt to handle exceedingly cursed cases, such as [a map with object properties](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map#setting_object_properties).

A test case for my answer, which demonstrates a few edge cases

```js
const originalValue = [
  new Map([['a', {
    b: {
      _meta: { __meta: "cat" },
      c: new Map([['d', 'text']])
    }
  }]]),
 { _meta: { type: "map" }}
];

console.log(originalValue);
let text = JSON.stringify(originalValue, stringifyReplacer);
console.log(text);
console.log(JSON.parse(text, parseReviver));
```

### Accepted answer not round-tripping

The accepted answer is really lovely. However, it does not round trip when an object with a `dataType` property is passed it it. That can make it dangerous to use in certain circumstances, such as

1. `JSON.stringify(data, acceptedAnswerReplacer)` and send it over the network.
2. Naive network handler automatically JSON decodes it.
   From this point on forth, you cannot safely use the accepted answer with the decoded data, since doing so would cause lots of sneaky issues.

This answer uses a slightly more complex scheme to fix such issues.

```js
// Test case for the accepted answer
const originalValue = { dataType: "Map" };
const str = JSON.stringify(originalValue, replacer);
const newValue = JSON.parse(str, reviver);
console.log(originalValue, str, newValue); 
// > Object { dataType: "Map" } , Map(0)
// Notice how the input was changed into something different
```

Answer (score 12):

Stringify a `Map` instance *(objects as keys are OK)*:

```
JSON.stringify([...map])
```

or

```
JSON.stringify(Array.from(map))
```

or

```
JSON.stringify(Array.from(map.entries()))
```

output format:

```
// [["key1","value1"],["key2","value2"]]
```

Answer (score 5):

The very simple way.

```
  const map = new Map();
  map.set('Key1', "Value1");
  map.set('Key2', "Value2");
  console.log(Object.fromEntries(map));
```

`
Output:-

`{"Key1": "Value1","Key2": "Value2"}`

Comment: Warning: Map can have non-string values as keys. This will not work if your Map keys are non-stringify-able types themselves :
`JSON.stringify(Object.fromEntries(new Map([['s', 'r'],[{s:3},'g']])))` becomes `'{"s":"r","[object Object]":"g"}'`

Answer (score 4):

Below solution works even if you have nested Maps

```
function stringifyMap(myMap) {
    function selfIterator(map) {
        return Array.from(map).reduce((acc, [key, value]) => {
            if (value instanceof Map) {
                acc[key] = selfIterator(value);
            } else {
                acc[key] = value;
            }

            return acc;
        }, {})
    }

    const res = selfIterator(myMap)
    return JSON.stringify(res);
}
```

Comment: Without testing your answer, I already appreciate how it brings attention to the problem of nested Maps. Even if you successfully convert this to JSON, any parsing done in the future has to have explicit awareness that the JSON was originally a `Map` and (even worse) that each sub-map (it contains) was also originally a map. Otherwise, there's no way to be sure that an `array of pairs` isn't just intended to be exactly that, instead of a Map. Hierarchies of objects and arrays do not carry this burden when parsed. Any proper serialization of `Map` would explicitly indicate that it is a `Map`.

Comment: More about that [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59114590/).

Answer (score 4):

You cannot call `JSON.stringify` on `Map` or `Set`.

You will need to convert:

- the `Map` into a primitive `Object`, using `Object.fromEntries`, or
- the `Set` into a primitive `Array`, using the spread operator `[...]`

…before calling `JSON.stringify`

### Map

```js
const
  obj = { 'Key1': 'Value1', 'Key2': 'Value2' },
  map = new Map(Object.entries(obj));

map.set('Key3', 'Value3'); // Add a new entry

// Does NOT show the key-value pairs
console.log('Map:', JSON.stringify(map));

// Shows the key-value pairs
console.log(JSON.stringify(Object.fromEntries(map), null, 2));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { top: 0; max-height: 100% !important; }
```

### Set

```js
const
  arr = ['Value1', 'Value2'],
  set = new Set(arr);

set.add('Value3'); // Add a new item

// Does NOT show the values
console.log('Set:', JSON.stringify(set));

// Show the values
console.log(JSON.stringify([...set], null, 2));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { top: 0; max-height: 100% !important; }
```

### toJSON method

If you want to call `JSON.stringify` on a class object, you will need to override the `toJSON` method to return your instance data.

```js
class Cat {
  constructor(options = {}) {
    this.name = options.name ?? '';
    this.age = options.age ?? 0;
  }
  toString() {
    return `[Cat name="${this.name}", age="${this.age}"]`
  }
  toJSON() {
    return { name: this.name, age: this.age };
  }
  static fromObject(obj) {
    const { name, age } = obj ?? {};
    return new Cat({ name, age });
  }
}

/*
 * JSON Set adds the missing methods:
 * - toJSON
 * - toString
 */
class JSONSet extends Set {
  constructor(values) {
    super(values)
  }
  toString() {
    return super
      .toString()
      .replace(']', ` ${[...this].map(v => v.toString())
      .join(', ')}]`);
  }
  toJSON() {
    return [...this];
  }
}

const cats = new JSONSet([
  Cat.fromObject({ name: 'Furball', age: 2 }),
  Cat.fromObject({ name: 'Artemis', age: 5 })
]);

console.log(cats.toString());
console.log(JSON.stringify(cats, null, 2));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { top: 0; max-height: 100% !important; }
```

Comment: There's a much easier way of serializing Maps and Sets to JSON, since JSON.stringify and JSON.parse have a second argument that lets you add custom rules. See my answer for an answer that correctly round-trips in all cases.

Answer (score 3):

Just want to share my version for both Map and Set JSON.stringify only.
I'm sorting them, useful for debugging...

```js
function replacer(key, value) {
    if (value instanceof Map) {
        const reducer = (obj, mapKey) => {
            obj[mapKey] = value.get(mapKey);
            return obj;
        };
        return [...value.keys()].sort().reduce(reducer, {});
    } else if (value instanceof Set) {
        return [...value].sort();
    }
    return value;
}
```

Usage:

```js
const map = new Map();
const numbers= new Set()
numbers.add(3);
numbers.add(2);
numbers.add(3);
numbers.add(1);
const chars= new Set()
chars.add('b')
chars.add('a')
chars.add('a')
map.set("numbers",numbers)
map.set("chars",chars)

console.log(JSON.stringify(map, replacer, 2));
```

Result:

```json
{
  "chars": [
    "a",
    "b"
  ],
  "numbers": [
    1,
    2,
    3
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The following method will convert a Map to a JSON string:

```
public static getJSONObj(): string {
    return JSON.stringify(Object.fromEntries(map));
}
```

**Example:**

```
const x = new Map();
x.set("SomeBool", true);
x.set("number1", 1);
x.set("anObj", { name: "joe", age: 22, isAlive: true });

const json = getJSONObj(x);

// Output:
// '{"SomeBool":true,"number1":1,"anObj":{"name":"joe","age":222,"isAlive":true}}'
```

Comment: This is the right answer unless I am missing something. All these other methods are making an absolute meal out of this.

Comment: This answer adds nothing new compared to Alok Somani's answer. Plus, it does not handle nested maps.

It also has the same bug as Rakesh Singh Balhara's answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
JSON.stringify(errorCodes, (_, value) =>
  value instanceof Map || value instanceof Set ? Array.from(value) : value
);
```

Comment: I don't see what this adds compared to the other answers on the page. 

It's very simple, but it doesn't handle most of the advanced cases (nested maps and round tripping).

Answer (score -1):

I really don't know why there are so many long awesers here. This short version solved my problem:

```js
const data = new Map()
data.set('visible', true)
data.set('child', new Map())
data.get('child').set('visible', false)

const str = JSON.stringify(data, (_, v) => v instanceof Map ? Object.fromEntries(v) : v)
// '{"visible":true,"child":{"visible":false}}'

const recovered = JSON.parse(str, (_, v) => typeof v === 'object' ? new Map(Object.entries(v)) : v)
// Map(2) { 'visible' => true, 'child' => Map(1) { 'visible' => false } }
```

Comment: This turns objects into maps, which isn't what one wants. Try it with `const data = {visible: true, child: {visible: false}}`. You'll recover two nested maps instead of recovering objects.

Check out my answer for an actually correct implementation.

Answer (score -6):

Although there would be some scenarios where if you were the creator of the map you would write your code in a separate 'src' file and save a copy as a .txt file and, if written concisely enough, could easily be read in, deciphered, and added to server-side.

The new file would then be saved as a .js and a reference to it sent back from the server. The file would then reconstruct itself perfectly once read back in as JS. The beauty being that no hacky iterating or parsing is required for reconstruction.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This sounds like a nice 10,000 foot process overview, but an actual implementation would be much more useful.

Comment: Well, it was more food for thought really than a total solution. Sorry I'm new here and not sure how to add my code to the comments as yet.

Comment: I don't get, why this is related to the question?