# Map bound to AngularJS scope becomes empty object

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, ecmascript-6

Whenever I try to bind a [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) to the scope, it is replaced with an empty object during the digest cycle. Can anyone explain why this is happening?

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.testMap = new Map();
    $scope.testMap.set("testKey", "testValue");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
  <pre>{{testMap}}</pre>
</div>
```

Comment: It not gets replaced, it's only rendered this way. You can still use it, however I think change detection does not work on sets and maps.

Comment: Are you sure the `Map` is being replaced with an empty object? There's nothing magical happening in the code you've shown. Maybe the problem is that how Angular evaluates the expression `{{testMap}}`? Have you tried `{{testMap | json}}` or `{{testMap.get('testKey')}}`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Transforming a Map to JSON is not supported (or, to be precise, the entries of the map are not serialized as if they were the fields of a regular object).

So Angular can't display the content of the map (the json filter is implicitly used when displaying an object using `{{ testMap }}`.

Demonstration: http://plnkr.co/edit/AjJWNGXZLR5KhhJ8cz0g?p=preview

Related: [How do you JSON.stringify an ES6 Map?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29085197/how-do-you-json-stringify-an-es6-map)