# Issues Uploading JSON to s3 using node.js

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, amazon-s3

I am new to amazon s3 and am trying to use node.js to upload JSON into a file. My object is `users`, and it has a bunch of keys and values in it. Here is how I'm uploading it:

```
 s3.putObject({Bucket: 'currenteventstest',Key: 'users.json',Body: users, ContentType: "application/json"});
```

However, when I re download it, it's just an empty object.

Comment: Is `users` a JS object, or actual JSON? It should be the latter, so if it's the former, you need to use `JSON.stringify` or something equivalent.

Comment: I have tried using `JSON.stringify` and it also does not work.

Comment: Please show the relevant code, including sample content of `users`. Also, have you checked the result of your `putObject` call? You should add event handlers for `success` and `error`, and log details.

Comment: I added event handler and it works.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Adding a callback function fixes the problem:

```
s3.putObject({
  Bucket: 'currenteventstest',
  Key: 'users.json',
  Body: JSON.stringify(users),
  ContentType: "application/json"},
  function (err,data) {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(err) + " " + JSON.stringify(data));
  }
);
```

Comment: I've got something similar going on but keep getting `Cannot read property 'Location' of undefined`

Answer (score 9):

I don't have enough reputation to comment, but for what its worth with the new aws-sdk version you can use the promise chain when posting the JSON instead of a callback:

```
try{
   await s3.putObject({
        Bucket: 'currenteventstest',
        Key: 'users.json',
        Body: JSON.stringify(users),
        ContentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8'
    }).promise();
}
catch(e){
   throw e
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`JSON.stringify` is the way to create a JSON file on S3.

AWS accepts serialized JSON string as Body.

```js
s3.putObject({
    Bucket: 'currenteventstest',
    Key: 'users.json',
    Body: JSON.stringify(users),
    ContentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8'
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I had an ES6 Map in my data, which gets stringified to empty by default. I had to refer to below answer to address the issue by manually adding a `replacer` function to the `JSON.Stringify`

[How do you JSON.stringify an ES6 Map?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29085197/how-do-you-json-stringify-an-es6-map)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).