# Upload JSON file to aws s3 bucket from aws-sdk in node.js

Tags: node.js, amazon-s3, aws-sdk, multer, multer-s3

I am receiving an array of objects from 3rd party API and I want to store its data to S3 bucket in JSON file. Below are the steps which I want to achieve

1> Create new JSON file in S3 bucket
I have following:

```
var AWS = require('aws-sdk')
var express = require('express')
var multer = require('multer')
var multerS3 = require('multer-s3')
AWS.config.loadFromPath('./lib/configFile.json');
var s3 = new AWS.S3();
var data =  [
             {
              name: abc,
              address: xyz, def-12345
             },{
              name: fgh,
              address: cvb, def-09876
             },{
              name: jkl,
              address: nbm, def-34566
             }
            ]
```

Now, I want to upload this data as a JSON file in S3 bucket.
**Is there any way to upload this data to S3 without creating any temporary json file in a path and directly store this data to S3.**

2> Already have JSON file on S3:
   Let's say I already have JSON file on S3 bucket and I want to update the same file. **So, to achieve this is there any way to directly store JSON data somewhere temporarily and update this file.**

**What is the best way to achieve this?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I know this is late. But my comment may help some other.

A few days back even I had the same situation. I had javascript object which was huge. I looked for a solution. Then I looked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44379666).

I created a generic function to upload a file which might be buffer, base64 or JSON data.

```
let data = {
  version: "2.3.4",
  objects: [{
    a: "imagas dae",
    verasdasdsion: "2.3.4",
    originX: "center",
    originY: "center"
  }],
  background: "#232326",
  canvasWidth: 619,
  canvasHeight: 413
}
uploadFile(JSON.stringify(data), 'test.json').then(r=>{}).catch(e=>{})



function uploadFile(file, file_name, path = '/defualt') {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        if (Buffer.isBuffer(file) || (file && Buffer.isBuffer(file.buffer)) || String(file_name).includes('.json') || file.indexOf('data:') === 0) {
            file = Buffer.isBuffer(file) ? file : String(file_name).includes('.json') ? file : file.indexOf('data:') === 0 ? new Buffer(img_src.replace(/^data:\w+\/\w+;base64,/, ""), 'base64') : file.buffer;
            var data = {
                Key: file_name,
                Body: file,
                Bucket: "path/to/your/bucket" + path,
                CacheControl: 'no-cache'
            };


            if (file.indexOf('data:') === 0) {
                data['ContentType'] = String(file).substr(file.indexOf('data:') + 'data:'.length, file.indexOf(';'))
            } else if (String(file_name).includes('.json')) {
                data['ContentType'] = 'application/pdf';
            }

            s3.putObject(data, function (err, data) {
                if (err) {
                    console.log('Error uploading data: ', err);
                    return reject(err);
                } else {
                    return resolve({
                        name: file_name,
                        path: path
                    });
                }
            });
        } else {
            return reject('File is required');
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For someone else struggling with this issue, you can just use the Buffer object that is bundled with Nodejs.

https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html#buffer

```
import { PutObjectCommand, S3Client } from '@aws-sdk/client-s3'

const REGION = 'xxxxxx-xxxxx'
const client = new S3Client({
  region: REGION,
  credentials: {
    accessKeyId: xxx-xxx-xxx,
    secretAccessKey: xxx-xxx-xxx,
  },
})

const sendToS3 = async ({ item1, item2 }) => {
  
  const configData = {
    name: item1,
    description: item2,
  }

  var buffer = Buffer.from(JSON.stringify(configData))

  const command = new PutObjectCommand({
    Bucket: 'bucket-name',
    Key: `${configData.slug}.json`,
    Body: buffer,
    ContentEncoding: 'base64',
    ContentType: 'application/json',
  })

  try {
    const response = await client.send(command)
    console.log(response)
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err)
  }
}

sendToS3({
   item1: "foo",
   item2: "bar",
})
```