# JSON Object Deserialization with Nested Map, Java Spring

Tags: javascript, java, json, spring, spring-boot

From what I have searched and found this very well may not be possible but any help would be appreciated.

I have a spring controller that accepts a DTO that I have created and one of the attributes is a Map. On my html page I am trying to bundle a map from the page into the JSON but the only way I have found to do this is to convert the map into an array. This causes the deserialization to fail because of incompatible types.

E.G.

Controller:

```
@PostMapping("/mapping")
public ResponseEntity addThing(@Validated @RequestBody Dto dto, BindingResult result){
    //Do some stuff
}
```

Dto:

```
public class Dto {
     ...
     private Map<Integer, String> map;
     ...
}
```

Javascript:

```
...
var map = new Map();
$("#mapBody tr").map(function () {
     var value = $(this).find( "input[name=value]").val();
     var index = $(this).find("input[name=index]").val();
     map.set(index, value);
});
...
var data = {
//other values
"map": Array.from(map.entries()), //This is what I have found so far but 
                                  //this is what I believe needs to be changed
//Some more values
}
...
$.ajax({
   url: "/mapping",
   type: "POST",
   data: JSON.stringify(data),
   ...
});
```

As mentioned above, the changing into an array makes the deserialization fail, but otherwise the stringify makes the map into just: {} which I know is the expected behavior.

Is there anyway I can change this to make it do what I would like it to?

EDIT:
This is the result of the stringify with the Array.from()

```
"{
  //values
  "map":[["0","value"],["1","another value"],["2","third value"]], 
  //more values
 }"
```

And like I mentioned above, if I just use "map":map then the resulting parsing is "map":{}

Comment: Please post what your JSON actually looks like.

Comment: Looks you have key as string in JSON, but you are trying to assign it to Map<Integer, String>

Comment: @vlad324 That's a good point. Any idea how I can make sure that those are integers instead of strings after the Array.from(map.entries())?

Comment: @G.Blandin try this one map.set(parseInt(index), value); never mind, stupid idea

Comment: @vlad324 I found using Number($(this).find("input[name=index]").val()); made it a number so that works, however this still does not fix the deserialization issue.

Comment: @G.Blandin I think you shoudn't use Array.from(map.entries()), becuase jackson expect your object to be look like this:
{
  // other values
  "map" : {
    "1" : "val1",
    "2" : "val2",
    "3" : "val3"
  }
}

Comment: @G.Blandin and my idea about cast to int is stupid, because in resulting json it will be everything wrapped in " "

Comment: @vlad324 The issue is that JSON.stringify does not support maps so when that is called on a nested map, the result is {}.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just thought a little about your problem. We can't serialize JS `Map()` properly ([Problems with JS map serialization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29085197/how-do-you-json-stringify-an-es6-map)), so my preposition is to change your code in this way:

```
...
var map = {}; // using object instead of map 
$("#mapBody tr").map(function () {
     var value = $(this).find( "input[name=value]").val();
     var index = $(this).find("input[name=index]").val();
     map[index] = value; // setting property of object
});
...
var data = {
//other values
"map": map, // using map object instead of array
//Some more values
}
...
$.ajax({
   url: "/mapping",
   type: "POST",
   data: JSON.stringify(data),
   ...
});
```

So resulting JSON looks like this:

```
'{"id":1,"map":{"1":"val1","2":"val2","3":"val3"},"otherProperty":"otherValue"}'
```

And this one is parsable to DTO with `HashMap<Integer, String> map` inside. Try it please and let me know if it works.

Comment: Thanks a bunch! This solved the issue. I didn't think just using an object would map correctly but it did. Thanks again!