# Preferred way to serialize/deserialize js-joda LocalDate?

Tags: json, serialization, ecmascript-6, js-joda

We are using js-joda LocalDate to represent various dates in our model and are storing those dates in sessionStorage. Is there a generalized preferred way of storing those dates so that they can serialize/deserialize without adding special code to each object that contains them?

We have been using the standard `JSON.stringify` / `JSON.parse` to do this, but since `LocalDate` converts to an ISO string when stringified, we lose its `LocalDate` type when we parse it back.

As demonstrated [here](https://runkit.com/bbernstein/5db053ff4d42bf00135259e3)

Here's the summary:

```
const myObj = { a: "thing", d: LocalDate.parse('2019-01-20') };
const stringified = JSON.stringify(myObj);
const parsed = JSON.parse(stringified);

// this fails because d is no longer a LocalDate
console.log(parsed.d.year());
```

Our workaround now is that we have custom deserializers for any class that contains a LocalDate, but it seems a little kludgy.

Seeking a cleaner solution for this. Perhaps we could make a generalized serializer for LocalDate that outputs the same thing as the `%o` modifier in console.log?

```
mydate -> serialize -> "LocalDate { _year: 2019, _month: 1, _day: 20}"
```

Before we do that, I'm looking to see if this has already been done cleanly or if I'm just missing something obvious.

Comment: Ran into the same issue. Ended up adding a field `$type` to the JSON that stored a tag representing what the type is.

Answer (score 2):

Answering my own question.

I'm surprised it hasn't come up, but the solution is right there in the definitions of `JSON.stringify` and `JSON.parse`.

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29085197/how-do-you-json-stringify-an-es6-map) pointed me to the solution when I needed to do the same thing with a Map.

```
JSON.parse(text[, reviver])
JSON.stringify(value[, replacer[, space]])
```

I needed to add replacers and revivers to do the custom serialization:

```
function myReviver(key: string, value: any) {
    if (value === undefined) return undefined;
    if (value === null) return null;
    if (typeof value === 'object') {
        switch (value.dataType) {
            case 'LocalDate':
                return LocalDate.parse(value.value);
            case 'LocalTime':
                return LocalTime.parse(value.value);
            case 'LocalDateTime':
                return LocalDateTime.parse(value.value);
            case 'Period':
                return Period.parse(value.value);
        }
    }
    return value;
}

function myReplacer(key, value) {
    const originalObject = this[key];
    if (originalObject instanceof LocalDate) {
        return {
            dataType: 'LocalDate',
            value: originalObject.toJSON()
        };
    } else if (originalObject instanceof LocalTime) {
        return {
            dataType: 'LocalTime',
            value: originalObject.toJSON()
        };
    } else if (originalObject instanceof LocalDateTime) {
        return {
            dataType: 'LocalDateTime',
            value: originalObject.toJSON()
        };
    } else if (originalObject instanceof Period) {
        return {
            dataType: 'Period',
            value: originalObject.toJSON()
        };
    } else {
        return value;
    }
}
```

Whenever I call stringify or parse, I add the above functions as their replacer/revivers.

```
JSON.stringify(mystuff, myReplacer);
JSON.parse(mystuff, myReviver);
```