# How to post Typescript Map object to ASP.Net Core WebAPI?

Tags: c#, angular, typescript, asp.net-core

In my Angular project, I have a Map object in an object.

For example:

```
export class Item {
   name: string;
   description: string;
   startValues: Map<string, number>;
}
```

I want to post this object to WebAPI that I wrote with ASP.Net Core. 
The object I defined on the API side;

```
public class ItemDto
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<string, decimal> StartValues { get; set; }
}
```

I didn't know how to handle the map object in C#. The first thing that came to my mind was to try it out with the Dictionary. But it didn't work.

[the object coming to the server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dyYZB.png)

How I post Typescript Map object to ASP.Net Core WebAPI? Can you help with this?

Comment: When you say it didn't work, do you mean the dictionary was null or empty? Could you show the JSON being sent to the server?

Comment: @juunas Thank you for quick answer. I shared the screenshot. The object comes empty.

Comment: Okay, can you share an example JSON data being sent to server?

Comment: I think Map should be an array of tuples.  `Tuple<string, int>[]`

Comment: @juunas When I print the object to the console, I see the Map object full. But when I print the object to the console as JSON, I see the Map object empty. Why can this be happening?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/29085197/1658906 this should answer your question

Comment: @juunas I understand that I can't do this with the Map object. Is it correct?

Comment: Yeah, it won't serialize to JSON.

Comment: @juunas Ok, thank you so much :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do something like below, Change the type of startValues property from Map

```
export class Item {
   name: string;
   description: string;
   startValues:{ [key: string]: number; };
}
```

And you can assign the values to it like below.

```
const sampleData : { [key: string]: number; } = {};
sampleData["key1"] = 10;
```

This will map to the Dictionary in .Net Core side.

Comment: Yes, I changed the property this way and it worked. Thank you :)